# hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear

Tags: hyperref, citing, biblatex

I am using biblatex with the authoryear styles.

So far I've been able to find everything I need easily in the excellent documentation, but I'm stuck on one thing.

With my current settings (below) citations only have the year hyperlinked to the bibliography entry. I think prior to using biblatex I would have the whole citation (authors + year) as a reference - I think this is easier to click etc. when browsing.

Is there an easy way to get this (or does it involve creating a new style).

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            bibstyle=authoryear,
            citestyle=authoryear,
            natbib=true,
            hyperref=true,
            backref=true,
            abbreviate=true]{biblatex}
```

Comment: `style=authoryear, bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` is equivalent to the much shorter `style=authoryear,`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add the following to you preamble:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{ \usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

Note that this code snipped is basically taken from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/ad23e11b68dddcab) and adapted to biblatex v0.9b, i.e. the definitions for `\footcitetext` and `\textcite` are added resp. changed. (I also decided not to add hyperlinks for `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`.)

Comment: One thing I noticed with this is that for in text citations the closing bracket is not part of the hyperlink (although the rest of the text is) - so this looks a bit messy. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @thrope Another user has requested a similar feature [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/4483).

Comment: @robince Check out [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25972/73149).

Comment: It should be noted that `\printtext[bibhyperref]` in these places has the potential to confuse `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker. The solution is therefore not suitable for styles that make heavy use of the punctuation tracker (such as `...-comp` styles). The approach (probably) works fine with `style=authoryear,` from the question, but is problematic for `style=authoryear-comp,`. (Note that since the `\cite...` command are defined slightly differently in the  `-comp` styles, one should not copy the definitions directly anyway for those styles.)

Comment: This seems to break when making citations inside captions.

Comment: This also breaks the display of only the SHORTAUTHOR in a \cite. Instead, both the AUTHOR and the SHORTAUTHOR are shown

Answer (score 8):

The biblatex style [`apa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) (which is a modified authoryear style) does this for you. For example:

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

Note it is also recommended that you load the `csquotes` package.

It needs a relatively up to date version of biblatex to work.

Comment: I updated to MacTex / TexLive 2010 to try this but the apa style appears to be broken - my document wont compile with 
"Undefined control sequence. <argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra {year}{month}{day}" - same problem as here: http://www.developpez.net/forums/d984595/autres-langages/autres-langages/latex/bibtex/biblatex-style-apa/

Comment: Have you included the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` line? it _is_ necessary...

Comment: @thrope and, of course, got the right `babel` settings? This sounds like a localisation issue.

Comment: I'm using babel with [english] so I put the mapping as {english}{english-apa}... I had another go being more careful to delete all the intermediate files and it seemed to compile successfully (using bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=apa) - but it doesn't link the names... only the years of the citation are linked.

Comment: @thrope What kind of citation command are you using (`\textcite` `\parencite` etc?) and what version of biblatex and biblatex-apa do you have? `\textcite{key}` should have both as a link. If you add postnotes, prenotes or things like that `\textcite[postnote]{key}` then only the year gets linked.

Comment: @Seamus I am using `\parencite` with loaded option `style=apa`. Is there any recent solution to hyperlink both author and year?

Comment: This does not work for me using TexLive 2019. Only year in linked.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Overleag, even the year won't get linked

Comment: Doesn't work for me as well in Texmaker

Comment: Not working for me with TeX Live 2022

Answer (score 8):

As an addition to the answer provided by lockstep, the following code for `\textcite` includes the closing parenthesis in the link too, and, unfortunately, the space afterwards.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
 {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}%
      \printtext{ (\printfield{year}\printtext{)}}}}
 {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
  {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {}%
 \multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

Comment: This appears to give the desired output only for `\textcite{<entrykey>}`, but doesn't handle notes properly. `prenote` gets ignored entirely. `postnote` is enclosed in a second set of parentheses. For example `\textcite[postnote]{key}` gives `labelname (labelyear) (postnote)`, not `labelname (labelyear, postnote)`.

Comment: @Audrey Is there a workaround to the issue you are highlighting?