# hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)

Tags: hyperref, biblatex

I'm new here so I'm not sure if this is the right way to express my question:

I'm using the excellent biblatex package with the author-year style and want the links in my citations to include the name of the author as well as the parentheses.
The answer presented at [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear) did exactly what I wanted but it seems the solution is broken with the newest biblatex version 1.4b. Can anyone help me by adapting the code to the newest biblatex version?

Comment: It's always best to provide a minimal example that we can test. Can you put one together, using some of the references in the `biblatex` example database if possible.

Comment: I tried and got the expected result.

Comment: Sorry, I checked again and it indeed works as in earlier versions. The reason I thought it was broken is a behaviour that looks awkward to me. If I use \textcite{key} the closing parenthesis after the date is not included in the hyperlink which looks awkward with colored links. It does make sense if you provide a page number like for example \textcite[27]{key}, but for a plain citation without a page number I think it would look better if the closing parenthesis was included. Is there a way to achieve this? Sorry for the mixup. Should I rather edit the whole question?

Comment: Please provide an example we can test to see what you mean.

Comment: Also relevant: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/428

Answer (score 60):

The code below hyperlinks the entire citation label for most citation commands. For `\textcite` the hyperlink includes the brackets around `labelyear`+`extrayear`, unless there are pre- or postnotes. In this case the link is applied only to `labelyear`+`extrayear`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Just for demo
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
  }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\textbf{Single citations}

Filler text \parencite{aristotle:poetics}. Filler text \parencite{kant:ku} \\
Filler text \parencite[See][23]{aristotle:poetics}.
Filler text \parencite[1--10]{kant:ku}. \\
\textcite{aristotle:poetics} and \textcite{kant:ku}.
\textcite[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics} and \textcite[10]{kant:ku}. \\
Filler text.\footcite[23]{aristotle:poetics} Filler text.\footcite[1--10]{aristotle:rhetoric}
Filler text.\footnote{\smartcite[10--15]{companion}}

\textbf{Unqualified citation lists}

\textcite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcite[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcite[10--15]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcite[e.g.][10--15]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\parencite[See][for example]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}

\textbf{Qualified citation lists}

\textcites{aristotle:poetics}{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcites(See)(){aristotle:poetics}[cf.][]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcites(See)()[10]{aristotle:poetics}[10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcites(See)()[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcites(See)()[e.g.][10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\parencites(See)()[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric}

\textbf{Mix of qualified and unqualified citation lists}

\textcites(See)()[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics}[10]{bertram,companion} \\
\textcites[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}[10]{companion} \\
\textcites[10]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}[cf.][]{bertram} \\
\textcites[15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{bertram,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the output you should obtain with biblatex 2.6 or earlier. The solution also works for later releases, where `\textcite` and friends use the `and` string as a final citation delimiter.

[image]

Comment: Why is this not an option in biblatex yet?

Comment: Hmm, I rather think it should be the default.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this… it works great except for one detail: when you do `\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}` it causes text formatted as `bibhyperref` to ignore whether it's inside an `emph` command or something like that. The text always show up in the regular roman type, even when it should be in italics. Any ideas?

Comment: Uhm, nevermind… I must have redefined `noformat` somewhere. When I just define `bibhyperref` to `{#1}` it works out fine.

Comment: has the feature eventually found its way into the biblatex package? can someone point me to the section where it is explained in the documentation?

Comment: **Update 2021:** Reason why this is *not* part of BiBLaTeX: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1024 (2020) and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/428 (2016).

Comment: I see I'm a decade late to this party. But a sketch of what the code above is doing would be much appreciated.