# Follow-up question to: hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I'm new here, so I don't know whether I should be creating a new question for this, since this is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear-biblatex-1-4b).

I'm trying to get both the name and the year in `biblatex`'s citations to work as hyperlinks. The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear-biblatex-1-4b/27107#27107) given by Audrey in the original post seems to work great, except for one thing: If multiple entry keys are used within a single `\cite` command, the delimiter between citations does not show up.

I tried adding a `\multicitedelim` after the year label, and it works, except that I end up with a semicolon after the final citation too. Thoughts?

Comment: +1 Thanks for catching this. There is indeed a problem with `\textcite{key1,key2}` - I forgot to reset a parenthesis flag. I'll update my original answer instead of providing a new one for now. I can't produce any problems with the remaining citation commands. If the fix doesn't solve your problem, could you provide some further details? Some code and biblatex version would be great.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I will give it a try and get back to you if it doesn't work.

Comment: It works as advertised. Thanks! I am assuming that redefining `\parencite` along the lines of your definition of `\textcite` should work as well.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to do that. But by simply adding the definitions of `\parencite` from `authoryear.cbx` it now works for `\parencite` too.

Comment: Have a look at the sample document. The code redefines a macro used by all citation commands (under the `authoryear` style) except `\textcite`. So it should affect the output of `\parencite` without direct edits to this command. To take this post off the unanswered list, I can provide an answer with details on the bug fix. But feel free to request another feature. Maybe the inclusion of `postnote` in hyperlinks generated by `\textcite`?

Comment: I see. I don't know why it wasn't working before? One more question (and I'll stop, I promise!): any way of making it work with authoryear-comp? I tried modifying the definition of `\cite` in `authoryear-comp.cbx` along the lines of what you did, but I get an error message: `Latex Error: ./biblatex.tex:96 Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
Runaway argument?` Here's the code: http://snipt.org/xnrp

Comment: Hard to say why it wasn't working - sometimes deleting auxiliary files and compiling from scratch helps. But you shouldn't have to redefine `\parencite` to get it to work. The code as-is cannot be extended to compact variants of `authoryear`. Recurrent names and years in labels are subject to truncation. For example `Doe (1990a); Doe (1990b)` becomes `Doe (1990a,b)`. The two hyperlinks are tied to `1990a` and `b`. I'm pretty sure it is possible to work out a solution that hyperlinks a "maximal" portion of the label. To get this problem some more attention, feel free to edit your question.

Comment: That's very helpful. I'll create a new question, to see if anyone else knows what to do with `authoryear-comp`. _This_ question has been more than adequately answered.

Answer (score 3):

(Just repeating my comment in an answer to take this question off the unanswered list.)

The question uncovers a bug. For the parenthesis printed in the hyperlink, I didn't reset a flag `biblatex` uses to track parentheses. In particular

`\bibcloseparen`

needs to followed up with

`\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}`

I've edited the answer to incorporate this fix.