# Hyperlink with authoryear-comp in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, hyperref

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

% Combine label and labelyear links
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
{\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
{\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}{}{}

% Include labelname in labelyear link
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
{\printnames{labelname}%
\setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
{\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}{}{}

% Access hyperref's citation link start/end commands
\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@imc@biblinkstart{%
\@ifnextchar[%]
    {\blx@biblinkstart}
    {\blx@biblinkstart[\abx@field@entrykey]}}
\def\blx@biblinkstart[#1]{%
\blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkstart{\the\c@refsection @#1}\blx@sfrest}
\protected\def\blx@imc@biblinkend{%
\blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkend\blx@sfrest}
\blx@regimcs{\biblinkstart \biblinkend}
\makeatother

\newbool{cbx:link}

% Include parentheses around labelyear in \textcite only in
% single citations without pre- and postnotes
\def\iflinkparens{%
\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumequal{\value{multicitetotal}}{0}} and
            test {\ifnumequal{\value{citetotal}}{1}} and
            test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
            test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} }}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
{\printnames{labelname}}
{\iflinkparens
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:link}\biblinkstart%
    \printnames{labelname}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
{\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
{\iflinkparens
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:link}\biblinkstart%
    \usebibmacro{cite:label}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{textcite:postnote}
{\ifbool{cbx:link}% patch 2.7+
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}%
        \biblinkend\global\boolfalse{cbx:link}}
        {}}
{}
{\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}% patch earlier releases
    {\setunit{%
        \ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}%
        \multicitedelim}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:link}
        {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}%
        \biblinkend\global\boolfalse{cbx:link}}
        {}%
    \setunit{%
        \ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}%
        \multicitedelim}}
    {}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \textcite{knuth:ct:e}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Bibliography}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Since I want hyperlink in citations to include the name of the author and not just the year, I'm using, after the line that begins with `\hypersetup`, the code in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27615/9953). However by doing this I'm getting the error: `Undefined control sequence`.

The problem might be with this part of the code:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
    {\printnames{labelname}}
    {\iflinkparens
        {\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
        \global\booltrue{cbx:link}\biblinkstart%
        \printnames{labelname}}
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}}{}{}
```

When I remove it, the error goes away but I don't get the desired result of hyperlinking both the author and the year.

Comment: Which code? ....

Comment: @cfr See my updated question please.

Comment: And how is the biblatex code integrated in your example `.tex` file?  That file has its own problem: you use `\hypersetup` without first loading the `hyperref` package.  Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` before the line `\hypersetup`.

Comment: @jon Mm I'm pretty sure beamer loads hyperref by default (adding it explicitly still generates the error). In the post I state how the code is integrated in my file: after the `\hypersetup` line.

Comment: Ah, true.  Never noticed that before.  However, I can compile your `.tex` file without problems --- is the posted file the one that is causing the problems?  Because, if so, then none of the `biblatex` code can be the culprit, since it is *not* being used in the example file.  And if you are simply adding those lines in your preamble, that will fail miserably for a few reasons.  Please edit your question so that you have one complete file that leaves no guesswork to others.

Comment: @jon Thanks, I've edited the question accordingly. Can you check if you can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the problematic part of your code with

```
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
{\printnames{labelname}}
{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}{}{}
```

You get a clickable author name and year. Only the space between and the parenthesis remain unclickable. Is this enough clickability?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

% Combine label and labelyear links
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
{\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
{\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}{}{}

% Include labelname in labelyear link
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
{\printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
{\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
        \printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}{}{}

% Access hyperref's citation link start/end commands
\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@imc@biblinkstart{%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\blx@biblinkstart}
    {\blx@biblinkstart[\abx@field@entrykey]}}
\def\blx@biblinkstart[#1]{%
    \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkstart{\the\c@refsection @#1}\blx@sfrest}
\protected\def\blx@imc@biblinkend{%
    \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkend\blx@sfrest}
\blx@regimcs{\biblinkstart \biblinkend}
\makeatother

\newbool{cbx:link}

% Include parentheses around labelyear in \textcite only in
% single citations without pre- and postnotes
\def\iflinkparens{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumequal{\value{multicitetotal}}{0}} and
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{citetotal}}{1}} and
        test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
        test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} }}

%\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
%{\printnames{labelname}}
%{\iflinkparens
%   {\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
%       \global\booltrue{cbx:link}\biblinkstart%
%       \printnames{labelname}}
%   {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
{\printnames{labelname}}
{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
{\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
{\iflinkparens
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
        \global\booltrue{cbx:link}\biblinkstart%
        \usebibmacro{cite:label}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{textcite:postnote}
{\ifbool{cbx:link}% patch 2.7+
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}%
        \biblinkend\global\boolfalse{cbx:link}}
    {}}
{}
{\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}% patch earlier releases
    {\setunit{%
            \ifbool{cbx:parens}
            {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
            {}%
            \multicitedelim}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:link}
        {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
            {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
            {}%
            \biblinkend\global\boolfalse{cbx:link}}
        {}%
        \setunit{%
            \ifbool{cbx:parens}
            {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
            {}%
            \multicitedelim}}
    {}{}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \textcite{knuth:ct:e}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Bibliography}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```