# Disable hyperlinks for citations

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:foo}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\textcite{salam}
\ref{eq:foo}
\end{document}
```

Since apparently there is no answer for this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202587/hyperlink-with-authoryear-comp-in-beamer) of mine I was wondering if its is possible to disable hyperlinks for texcite citations. In the MWE this means if it possible to have hyperlinks for the equation but not for the (textcite) citation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eliminating footnote links requires setting two options:

1. the `hyperref=false` option for `biblatex`, and
2. the `hyperfootnotes=false` option for `hyperref`.

This example should make clear that the citation at the beginning has no link, but the equation at the end does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@book{salam,
    author={Salam},
    title={Salam's Book},
    year={1976},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\textcite{salam}

\lipsum

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:foo}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\ref{eq:foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to enable hyperlinks for backrefs while disabling them for citations?

Comment: If pass the `backref=true` option to biblatex and set `hyperref=false`, the backrefs are printed but not hyperlinked. I was wondering if it is possible to hyperlink them.