# How to remove hyperlinks of citations (of publications) in LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, hyperlink

How can I remove hyperlinks of citations (of publications) in the pdf generated from my TeX? I notice that when some hyperlinks spill across multiple columns or pages, LaTeX compilation throws errors. I wish to avoid that.

I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235417/disable-hyperlinks-for-citations) post from tex.stackexchange which speaks of similar things, but it appears slightly different to what I need.

This is the skeleton of my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{pdflscape}  % Landscape pages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}

\title[heading]{Title}

\author[Author et al.]{
Author1$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: author@univ.edu}
\\
$^{1}$University 1
}

\date{Accepted XXX. Received YYY; in original form ZZZ}

\pubyear{2018}

\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Some introduction. Papers: \citep[][]{Kolb2006, Haavard2006, Bene2006, Krasinski2010, Chatterjee2011, Celerier2014, Skarke2014, Mertens2016}

\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{ref}

\bsp    % typesetting comment
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

The `ref.bib` that I am using can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ns4g_ibgOSXGXO1-E8BRV2kYg2dMzAjp/view?usp=sharing).

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: How are you putting them in? LaTeX doesn't hyperlink anything by default, so the truthful answer is 'you need do nothing', but presumably you are putting them in for some reason (probably as a side-effect of something you do want). The question is how.

Comment: Thanks cfr, Kurt. I have edited my post. The new version of the post has more details of the options that I am using in my latex file.

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy This isn't a compilable document. It needs to begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`.  And it doesn't show anything do do with citations, which is the relevant part of the problem. So remove all the packages that aren't part of the problem, and show (e.g. `multicol`, `bm`, `amsmath`, etc.) and show us how you are producing a citation. You can include a single `.bib` file item as well.

Comment: Also, is the problem with the links from the text to the reference list, or is the problem with URLs in the reference list?

Comment: @Alan Munn, thanks for your suggestion. I have included `.bib` file and have modified my post. The problem is with URLs in the reference list.

Comment: Which error do you get from the links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `\hypersetup{nolinks=true}` to get rid of all hyperlinks in your document.

As far as I can see there are some errors in your `bib` file, for example in entry

```
@article{White2011,
  author={Martin White and M. Blanton and A. Bolton and D. Schlegel and J. Tinker and A. Berlind and L. da Costa and E. Kazin and Y.-T. Lin and M.
Maia and C. K. McBride and N. Padmanabhan and J. Parejko and W. Percival and F. Prada and B. Ramos and E. Sheldon and F.
de Simoni and R. Skibba and D. Thomas and D. Wake and I. Zehavi and Z. Zheng and R. Nichol and Donald P. Schneider and Michael A.
Strauss and B. A. Weaver and David H. Weinberg},
  title={The Clustering of Massive Galaxies at z ~ 0.5 from the First Semester of BOSS Data},
  journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
  volume={728},
  number={2},
  pages={126},
  url={http://stacks.iop.org/0004-637X/728/i=2/a=126},
  year={2011},
  abstract={We calculate the real- and redshift-space clustering of massive galaxies at z ~ 0.5 using the first semester of data by the Baryon Oscillation Spectroscopic Survey (BOSS). We study the correlation functions of a sample of 44,000 massive galaxies in the redshift range 0.4 < z < 0.7. We present a halo-occupation distribution modeling of the clustering results and discuss the implications for the manner in which massive galaxies at z ~ 0.5 occupy dark matter halos. The majority of our galaxies are central galaxies living in halos of mass 10 13 h –1 M ☉ , but 10% are satellites living in halos 10 times more massive. These results are broadly in agreement with earlier investigations of massive galaxies at z ~ 0.5. The inferred large-scale bias ( b ##IMG## [http://ej.iop.org/icons/Entities/sime.gif] {sime} 2) and relatively high number density ( ##IMG## [http://ej.iop.org/images/0004-637X/728/2/126/apj378616ieqn1.gif] {$\bar{n}=3\times 10^{-4}\,h^3\,{\rm Mpc}^{-3}$} ) imply that BOSS galaxies are excellent tracers of large-scale structure, suggesting BOSS will enable a wide range of investigations on the distance scale, the growth of large-scale structure, massive galaxy evolution, and other topics.}
}
```

To get correct syntax for LaTeX you need to change `10%` to `10\%`. But at last I think you can delete all abstracts in your `bib` file, they are not printed ...

If I compile the following MWE I get only some warnings regarding that for example for `bib` entry `Amendola2017` an resulting empty hperlink is suppressed:

Bib entry:

```
@ARTICLE{Amendola2017,
author        = {{Amendola}, L. and {Kunz}, M. and {Saltas}, I.~D. and {Sawicki}, I.},
title         = "{The fate of large-scale structure in modified gravity after GW170817 and GRB170817A}",
journal       = {ArXiv e-prints},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
eprint        = {1711.04825},
keywords      = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, 
                 General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, 
                 High Energy Physics - Theory},
year          = 2017,
month         = nov,
adsurl        = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv171104825A},
adsnote       = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
}
```

`\bibitem` in `*.bbl` file:

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{{Amendola}, {Kunz}, {Saltas}  \&
  {Sawicki}}{{Amendola} et~al.}{2017}]{Amendola2017}
{Amendola} L.,  {Kunz} M.,  {Saltas} I.~D.,   {Sawicki} I.,  2017, preprint,
  \href {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv171104825A} {} % <=========================
  (\mn@eprint {arXiv} {1711.04825})
```

Could it be that there is some information in the `bib` entry missing? Sorry, I do not know class `mras` and its spezifications ...

The complete MWE

```
\documentclass[%
% a4paper,
  fleqn,usenatbib
]{mnras}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ae,aecompl} % <============================================obsolete

\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{pdflscape}  % Landscape pages
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <===============================================last called
%\hypersetup{nolinks=true} % <==========================================

\title[heading]{Title}

\author[Author et al.]{
Author1$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: author@univ.edu}
\\
$^{1}$University 1
}

\date{Accepted XXX. Received YYY; in original form ZZZ}

\pubyear{2018}

\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Some introduction. 
Papers: \citep[][]{Kolb2006, Haavard2006, Bene2006, Krasinski2010, 
Chatterjee2011, Celerier2014, Skarke2014, Mertens2016}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{ref}

\bsp    % typesetting comment
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

results in the following page without compiling errors, only some warnings!

[image]

After uncomenting the `\hypersetup` I get the following result, without warnings:

[image]

Please note that packages `ae` and `aecompl` are obsolete, do not use them any longer!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `hyperref` package is creating the links in your document. I could not find
an option to switch this off in [their options summary](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/options.pdf) or [in their documentation](http://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), but from what I have found, the `cite` package is not compatible with the `hyperref` package so if you add the `cite` package to your preamble the links should disappear.

I know that this is a somewhat hacky solution, but it seems like those links cannot be switched off with options in `hyperref`.

Comment: Many thanks Patrick. Your comment is very helpful. I appreciate your help. =)