# Hyperref: linkg full citation

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I would like to color the entire citation. I am working with this citation style, using `biblatex`: Author Year. Hyperref is only coloring the year.

Also, I would like Year to be in parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=bibtex,url=false,maxcitenames=1,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[expansion=alltext,stretch=30]{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,pdftex,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{tesis.bib}

\begin{document}
```

Thanks in advance,

Joaquín

Comment: What about [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1687/35864), [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864) or [Biblatex, authoryear-comp, and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27607/35864)?

Comment: Were any of these links helpful? If not what were you missing?