# Biblatex, hyperlink postnote

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I want postnotes for inline citations to be hyperlinked, i.e. I want the authorname, year, and any postnotes hyperlinked (but not prenotes!).

I've used the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27607/biblatex-authoryear-comp-and-hyperlinks) to get authorname hyperlinked, but can't figure out how to add the postnote to the hyperlink.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=bibtex,hyperref]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\makeatletter
%Works without the last bracket ;-)
\let\abx@macro@citeOrig\abx@macro@cite
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
\bibhyperref{%
\let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
\abx@macro@citeOrig%
  }%
}
\let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
\renewbibmacro{textcite}{%
  \bibhyperref{%
    \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
    \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
  }%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document} 
A reference to \parencite[e.g.][3-4]{kastenholz}, \parencite[56]{bertram}, and~\textcite[12-14]{sigfridsson}.  
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

In the above example, ", pp.3-4" and ", p.56" should be hyperlinked for Kastenholz and Bertram, respectively (not the parentheses), while ", pp. 12-14)" should be hyperlinked for the Sigfridsson cite (parentheses included).

Any suggestions?

P.S. I'm compiling this in RStudio, which requires me to use backend=bibtex, so any solution must allow for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:
(answering after years because @aan user found that non answered question in a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510219/120578) from him/her)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=bibtex,hyperref]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\makeatletter
%Works without the last bracket ;-)
\let\abx@macro@citeOrig\abx@macro@cite
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
\bibhyperref{%
\let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
\abx@macro@citeOrig%
  }%
}
\let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
\renewbibmacro{textcite}{%
  \bibhyperref{%
    \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
    \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multiprenote}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}

\begin{document} 
A reference to \parencite[e.g.][3-4]{kastenholz}, \parencite[56]{bertram}, and~\textcite[12-14]{sigfridsson}.  
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```