# How to change the color of first half of parenthesis in citation?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, color

Hi I am using the `natbib` compatibility mode under `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, sorting=nyt, natbib,
            uniquename=false, maxbibnames=99, dashed=false]{biblatex}
```

I frequently use the citation format of author (year), that is `\citet`.

First, I wanted to have link for all parts of the citation -- author and year (default is just year). So I followed the solution here: [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}  
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%   
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}  
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}  
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%   
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}  
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]  
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]  
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%  
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}  
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]  
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%   
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}  
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}  
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%   
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}  
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

Then, I wanted to change color of the links to be blue, so I changed the setting in hyperset:

```
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}                
\hypersetup{  
  pdffitwindow=false, 
  pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}, 
  pdfnewwindow=true,     
  colorlinks=true,                % false: boxed links; true: colored links
  linkcolor=darkblue,             % Color of internal links
  citecolor=darkblue,             % Color of links to bibliography
  urlcolor=darkblue}              % Color of external links
```

However, once I call `\citet`, say XX(2000), the color for XX(2000 is in darkblue but the color for ) is in black.

Is there anyway to fix the color of ( to be black?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting fragments of code, can you combine them into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Linking `biblatex` citations is hard, take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27615/35864

Comment: Note that copying the answer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear which is for `style=authoryear` destroys some of the features of `style=authoryear-comp` which you are using.

Comment: I also tried "style=authoryear" and things seem to stay the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full linking is hard for `biblatex`. So there is a good reason why only the year is linked by default. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27615/35864 for a full-link solution that colours both parentheses for `\textcite`.

Alternatively, I could offer you this answer I once gave at golatex.de: https://golatex.de/biblatex-textcite-link-fehler-bei-einem-autor-t20366.html (at least I think it was me ...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
         style=authoryear-comp,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AuthorA2000,
author = {AuthorA},
title = {TitleA},
year = {2000}
}
@article{AuthorB2001,
author = {AuthorB},
title = {TitleB},
year = {2001}
}
@article{AuthorC2002a,
author = {AuthorC},
title = {TitleCa},
year = {2002}
}
@article{AuthorC2002b,
author = {AuthorC},
title = {TitleCb},
year = {2002}
}
@article{AuthorC2002c,
author = {AuthorC},
title = {TitleCc},
year = {2002}
}
@article{AuthorC2003,
   author = {AuthorC},
   title = {TitleC3},
   year = {2003}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\blx@imc@transparentprinttext}[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#2}
    {}
    {\ifblank{#1}
       {\let\blx@theformat\@firstofone}
       {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{ffd}{#1}{}}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {}
       {\blx@theformat{#2}}}}

\blx@regimcs{\transparentprinttext}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
   \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}
        {\csnumgdef{cbx@textcite@state@\the\c@citecount}{2}}
        {\csnumgdef{cbx@textcite@state@\the\c@citecount}{1}%
         \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
     {\csnumgdef{cbx@textcite@state@\the\c@citecount}{0}%
      \stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}


\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
   \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
   \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{citecount}+1}{\value{citetotal}}
      {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}}
      {\ifnumequal{\csuse{cbx@textcite@state@\the\numexpr\c@citecount+1\relax}}{0}
         {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
            {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
            {}}
         {}}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
   \printtext[citehyperref]{%
      \restorebibmacro{cite}%
      \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
   \ifboolexpr{
      ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
      or
      ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
   }
   {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
   {}%
   \transparentprinttext[textcitehyperref]{%
      \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
      \usebibmacro{textcite}}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

First, single cites which are working: \textcite{AuthorA2000} and so on \textcite{AuthorB2001} and so on \textcite{AuthorC2002a} and so on \textcite{AuthorC2002b} and so on \textcite{AuthorC2002c}. This works!
\par
Now combined: Different Authors \\
Two: \textcite{AuthorA2000,AuthorB2001}\\
Three: \textcite{AuthorA2000,AuthorB2001,AuthorC2002a}\\
Works again! \par
Now combined, single author same year
The problem if linking is on: \textcite{AuthorC2002a,AuthorC2002b,AuthorC2002c} \par
Same Author, diff year: Same problem: \textcite{AuthorC2002a,AuthorC2003}

\parencite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is a solution that never links (colours) the brackets. For `\cite`/`\parencite` we can use Audrey's approach from [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864). But for `\textcite` only want to additionally link the name, so we patch the `textcite` bibmacro with `xpatch` to link the labelname.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
         style=authoryear-comp,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
   \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
   \bibhyperref{#1}}

\savebibmacro{cite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
   \printtext[citehyperref]{%
      \restorebibmacro{cite}%
      \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\printnames{labelname}}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AuthorA2000,
author = {AuthorA},
title = {TitleA},
year = {2000}
}
@article{AuthorB2001,
author = {AuthorB},
title = {TitleB},
year = {2001}
}
@article{AuthorC2002a,
author = {AuthorC},
title = {TitleCa},
year = {2002}
}
@article{AuthorC2002b,
author = {AuthorC},
title = {TitleCb},
year = {2002}
}
@article{AuthorC2002c,
author = {AuthorC},
title = {TitleCc},
year = {2002}
}
@article{AuthorC2003,
   author = {AuthorC},
   title = {TitleC3},
   year = {2003}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
First, single cites which are working: \textcite{AuthorA2000} and so on \textcite{AuthorB2001} and so on \textcite{AuthorC2002a} and so on \textcite{AuthorC2002b} and so on \textcite{AuthorC2002c}. This works!
\par
Now combined: Different Authors \\
Two: \textcite{AuthorA2000,AuthorB2001}\\
Three: \textcite{AuthorA2000,AuthorB2001,AuthorC2002a}\\
Works again! \par
Now combined, single author same year
The problem if linking is on: \textcite{AuthorC2002a,AuthorC2002b,AuthorC2002c} \par
Same Author, diff year: Same problem: \textcite{AuthorC2002a,AuthorC2003}

\parencite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, first thanks a lot! I read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27615/35864 and tried the solution. However, my latex cannot compile symbols like @ -- I am also very confused what they do... I just want to author and year in color and parentheses in black.

Comment: Thanks! Now the codes compiled but nothing changed about the color...

Comment: @JamesH Which code did you compile and what output did you get? The code will colour both parentheses in blue in most situations, I hoped that would be OK for you as well (because I assumed you were only worried about the inconsistency and not about the actual colour of the parentheses.)

Comment: I tried the codes posted by Marco Daniel. I am actually hoping to change the color of parentheses to black...

Comment: @JamesH Ok, if you really want black parentheses, see the second code block in my edited answer above.

Comment: wow, it worked perfectly! you are a wizard. Thank you! So to make it clear for future friends: the codes moewe provided in the second window is for citet or textcite. I replaced the corresponding part in Audrey's approach and everything worked out!