# Cite same author with different articles (biblatex-aer)

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I want to cite two articles from the same author using `biblatex` with citation style `biblatex-aer` (https://github.com/dmsul/biblatex-aer). However, when I use `\textcite{key1,key2}`, I get e.g.

> Gurley and Shaw (1955), 1966

instead of

> Gurley and Shaw (1955, 1966)

Going into the code from `biblatex-aer`, it boils down to this code snippet:

```
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
  }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}
```

If I delete these lines, I receive the correct citation, however, `hyperref` does not color the whole name anymore rather only the year of publication.

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code used in https://github.com/dmsul/biblatex-aer/blob/master/biblatex-aer.tex to get full links in citations was taken from Audrey's answer to [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864). That answer was written with `style=authoryear,` in mind (it also works for some other styles), but `biblatex-aer` is based upon `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style, which is more similar to the much more complex `style=authoryear-comp,` (in addition `biblatex-chicago` itself is also *very* complex).

This means you need a different strategy for the links. The following variation is inspired by Audrey's code in [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864) and by my answer to [How to change the color of first half of parenthesis in citation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437717/35864).

I also updated the code for bold names in `biblatex-aer.tex` so that the following preamble completely replaces `biblatex-aer.tex` from https://github.com/dmsul/biblatex-aer/blob/master/biblatex-aer.tex.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, uniquename=false, noibid]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\blx@imc@transparentprinttext}[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#2}
    {}
    {\ifblank{#1}
       {\let\blx@theformat\@firstofone}
       {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{ffd}{#1}{}}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {}
       {\blx@theformat{#2}}}}

\newcommand*{\blx@imc@iffieldequalstr@swap}[2]{\iffieldequalstr{#2}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\blx@imc@iffieldequalsdefstring}[2]{%
  \expandafter\blx@imc@iffieldequalstr@swap\expandafter{#2}{#1}}

\blx@regimcs{\transparentprinttext \iffieldequalsdefstring}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}%
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\letbibmacro{orig:cite}{cite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \transparentprinttext[citehyperref]{%
    \usebibmacro{orig:cite}}}

\letbibmacro{orig:textcite}{textcite}
\letbibmacro{orig:textcite:postnote}{textcite:postnote}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \transparentprinttext[citehyperref]{%
    \usebibmacro{orig:textcite}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}
      {\usebibmacro{orig:textcite:postnote}}
      {}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\ifmknamebold{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifcurrentname{labelname}}
              or
              test {\iffieldequalsdefstring{labelnamesource}{\currentname}}}}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{default}{\ifmknamebold{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname}{#1}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\cite{sigfridsson,gaonkar:in,westfahl:space,westfahl:frontier,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Fully linked citations and bits of the bibliography (with bold labelnames/sortnames).]