# When does \DeclareDelimFormat require optional arguments [bib], [biblist], etc. and when it does not?

Tags: biblatex

I have been learning how to customize biblatex styles. Some examples:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}
```

What I find confusing is that the first one does not require `[bib]` but the second one does? How do you figure which ones require the optional argument and which ones don't?

Is checking the definition of every delim format in `biblatex.def` the only way? Or there is some rhyme or reason behind which ones require an optional argument like `[bib]`, `[biblist]`, `[textcite]` and which ones do not?

Comment: Optional arguments are not required. And my first step to find out what arguments a command accept is to look into the documentation.

Comment: Hint: If you have never read `texdoc biblatex` before, in "3.12.2 Context-sensitive Delimiters" it says: "If the optional comma-separated list of <contexts> is given, declare <name> only for those contexts." (p 129). Your question is really about metadata. Time spent with the manual is an investment, not a luxury loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While both `\DeclareFieldFormat` and `\DeclareDelimFormat` have optional arguments, their meaning is different. The optional argument for `\DeclareFieldFormat` is a list of entry types. For `\DeclareDelimFormat` it is a list of delimiter contexts.

The behaviour of field formats and delimiter formats with respect to the optional argument is analogous, though. In both cases (i.e. when a field format is used or when a context-sensitive delimiter is printed), the current entry type/context is established. If there is a type/context-specific definition for the current type/context, it is used. If there is no such type/context-specific definition, the generic definition (that is given via `\DeclareFieldFormat` or `\DeclareDelimFormat` without an optional argument) is used. Examples for `\DeclareFieldFormat` can be found in [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864). A longer discussion for `\DeclareDelimFormat` is in [Change/clean biber citestyle and extend hyperref box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471553/35864).

So yes, generally when you want to redefine field formats and context-sensitive delimiters, it is good to look up their original definitions as that makes it easier to figure out how to redefine them.

(In the case of `nametitledelim` you could even find that info in the `biblatex` documentation. But generally you cannot rely on the manual documenting every style aspect.)

---

On a purely syntactical TeXnical level, neither line in your example *requires* the optional argument (if an argument is required it should be a mandatory argument). But the lines will behave differently depending on whether or not an optional argument is present and they will do different things.