# Biblatex command \textcite not working with unified style on Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, linguistics

Every time I try to use the `\textcite` command in the "unified" style, I get an "undefined control sequence" error from Overleaf. But when I switch to the "authoryear" style, the error goes away. How do I fix this? Here's part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{example-sentences}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=unified, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

And here's the error message I get from Overleaf:

```
\blx@biblinkstart [#1]->\blx@sfsave 
                                    \hyper@natlinkstart {\the \c@refsection ...
l.23 ...ime today," from \textcite{rior_gen_2021}}
                                                  .
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@biblinkstart ...x@sfsave \hyper@natlinkstart 
                                                  {\the \c@refsection @#1}\b...
l.23 ...ime today," from \textcite{rior_gen_2021}}
                                                  .
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

And again, none of this happens if I use the authoryear style (but I would like to use the unified style instead). What should I do please?

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `unified`'s `\textcite` command requires that you load `hyperref`. It uses code inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27615/35864. See for example https://github.com/semprag/biblatex-sp-unified/issues/48.

[The documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-unified/biblatex-unified.pdf) states

> The unified citation style relies on hyperlinking between in-text citations and the
> bibliography. So, the `hyperref` package is required. It is automatically loaded
> by `sp.cls` but if you use a different document class and `hyperref` is not loaded
> by that class, you need to add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble as
> well.

Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your document preamble. (Note that apart from a few documented exceptions, `hyperref` should generally be the last package you load). The following MWE compiles just fine

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=unified]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Sigfridsson & Ryde (1998)]

as is, but will throw an error if you omit the `\usepackage{hyperref}` line.