# hyperlinking author names in biblatex when using \citeauthor

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

Using `biblatex`, the `\citeauthor` no longer is hyperlinked by default (as done in `natbib`). I am currently desperately looking for a way to make it a hyperlink ... any suggestion welcome

Answer (score 28):

Just apply the `bibhyperref` format in the citation command:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Definitions for `bibhyperref` and `\citeauthor` can be found in `biblatex.def`.

Comment: Why does this not work at `\citet{xy}` (I have `natbib=true` as option). I saw http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27107/9075 as possible solution, but seems to be very complicated.