# biblatex+hyperref: citetitle/citeauthor and get hyperlink

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I find myself frequently using the `\citetitle` and `\citeauthor` commands of `biblatex`. They are great commands, but they don't provide a hyperlink to the entry in the bibliography. TO overcome this, I have to use `\citetitle{Knuth} \cite{Knuth}` to get

*The Art of Computer Programming* [1]

where the [1] is hyperlinked to the bibliography. That doesn't look as nice as I would like.

What must I do to get a hyperlink to the bibliography by just using the `\citetitle` (or '\citeauthor`) command?

PS. I'm also using the `hyperref` package, but I think that's obvious.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both of these citations commands are defined in `biblatex.def`. To add links, you can redefine them in your document preamble or configuration file. A linked variant of `\citeauthor` is already addressed in [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75902). The `\citetitle` command can be revised similarly, although note that you may wish to swap the order of the `bibhyperref` and `citetitle` formats.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: That is a great answer. Sorry I didn't see the answer to `\citeauthor` in the previous question. 

I tried to do a similar thing for `\fullcite` but it didn't work. This is what I tried: `\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\thefield{entrytype}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
`

Comment: @Jeremy You need to wrap the output of the bibliography driver in the format: `\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usedriver{...}{...}}`. But I don't know why you need this; the citation gives all of the bibliographic data and the link would only lead you to redundant information. Moreover it can lead to nested links if the entry contains an URL or DOI. It is possible to link just part of the driver output, but the solution depends on which part you choose.

Comment: thank, that did the trick. Your statement about the full citation being in the paper is a good one. I think I want the full citation in both places, but I'll have to reconsider now.

Comment: @Jeremy I don't see a problem with repeating a full citation in the bibliography, just linking the them. The links are there to lead the reader to more detailed information about the citation. With a full citation the reader already has all the details.