# looking for equivalent to natbib's `\citepalias` in biblatex with active links using \hypersetup

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, pdf, natbib, links

I recently made the switch from `natbib` to `biblatex`. I've been using `\hypersetup` to make *active* links with `natbib`––it helps me navigate my document as I am working on it (see below for example).

`\citepalias` <strike>and `\citeauthor`</strike> does not generate hyperlinks when used under `biblatex`. `biblatex`'s `\citet` and `\citep` works great, but  my homemade (i.e. using `\citepalias`) ibid. doesn't generate hyperlinks (I solved the <strike>striked</strike> part, see update below).

Is there a better way to get active links with `biblatex`?

[image: natbib half ass]

Here is a small example using the LaTeX below in a file called `main.tex’

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{veblen1919place,
  title={The Place of Science in Modern Civilisation: and other essays},
  author={Veblen, Thorstein},
  year={1919},
  publisher={BW Huebsch}
}
@book{veblen2007theory,
  title={The theory of the leisure class},
  author={Veblen, Thorstein},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
 url = {http://www.test.org}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib=true, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}


\usepackage{hyperref}
            \hypersetup{
          pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1} % thanks, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26085/22939
                         }

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

 \defcitealias{veblen1919place}{ibid.:~}     

\noindent 
As \citeauthor*{veblen2007theory} has argued \citep[12--19]{veblen1919place} it is clear that $y$. Second,  \citet[12]{veblen1919place} also show $m$ and $x$ \citepalias[37]{veblen1919place}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### Update 2015-02:06 23:34:18Z

With the help of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75916/71924) (and [this for title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108349/71924)) I’ve solved my issue with `\citeauthor`.

Here iss the code

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

  \DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Look after update
[image: after update]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! The `natbib` option for `biblatex` is meant to ease the transition from the former to the latter. If you use the 'native' `biblatex` interfaces linking should be fine: is there a reason you are not?

Comment: @JosephWright, thank you for your fast and friendly response. I think I’m using `natbib=true` mainly because I come _straight_ from `natbib`. I took a look at the default `biblatex` cite commands and didn’t see any replacement for the `\citeauthor` and `\citepalias` commands. In particular the latter is important for me as I use it to randomly create aliases (a feature I quite appreciate). But maybe there is a smart way around this using  `biblatex`?

Comment: `biblatex` has four `\citeauthor` commands, though I'm not sure how it compares to `natbib`'s. If you are going to use `\defcitealias` to print 'ibid.', this is solvable by simply `\cite`-ing the same work two times in a row: `biblatex` has quite a sophisticated 'ibidtracker'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex`'s `natbib`-like commands `\citepalias` and `\citetalias` (whose definitions can be found in `blx-natbib.def`) can be turned into hyperlinked versions just as easily as the other commands

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetalias}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\@citealias{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citepalias}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\@citealias{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```

Note the `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` commands are needed in order for the `@` in `\@citealias` to work.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib=true, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetalias}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\@citealias{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citepalias}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\@citealias{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defcitealias{cicero}{DND} 

\begin{document}
As \citeauthor*{cicero} has argued  \citep[12]{cicero} it is clear that $y$. Second,  \citet[12]{cicero} also show $m$ and $x$ \citepalias[12]{cicero}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

In your use-case though, it seems much more appropriate to use a style that can do the "ibid"-work for you, in your case probably `authoryear-ibid`. Then there is no need to awkwardly alias an entry to "ibid" and `biblatex` tries its best to avoid ambiguous "ibid" citations for you.

Comment: Perfect! I do want to do it _awkwardly_ in my case as I am only using "ibid" inside some tables where the author(s) would take up too much place. Thank you for solving my problem!