# Citing and printing only last name of author(s) using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex

I would like a citation command to reference and print only the last name(s) of the author(s) of my sources while writing my thesis in `biblatex-chicago` (which would include an hyperlink as well).

What should I do to achieve this?

For example, given the following reference in my .bib file,

```
   @BOOK{GThomson,
   title = {Rethinking Secondary Education: A Human-Centred Approach},
   publisher = {Pearson Education},
   year = {2012},
   author = {{Gill, Scherto} and {Thomson, Garrett}},
   address = {Great Britain},
   edition = {1st}
   }
```

how can I reference the authors as "Gill and Thomson" in my thesis instead of "Gill, Scherto and Thomson, Garrett" (with an added `hyperlink` hopefully as well)?

Comment: Remove the braces around the author names as they prevent parsing into name parts (first name, last name, etc.): `author = {Gill, Scherto and Thomson, Garrett}`

Comment: If I do that, then the author names appear in the wrong order in the references.  Even if I successfully did that, what should I do next to cite the last name of the book authors?

Comment: I think you mean `author = { Gill Scherto and Thomson Garrett}` or `author = {Scherto, Gill and Garrett, Thomson}`

Comment: @AakarshGottumukkala The order isn't wrong; it conforms to the Chicago style. If you want to change it use, say: `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`. To cite the author's last names, use `\citeauthor{GThomson}`. To add a hyperlink, [redefine `\citeauthor`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75902).

Comment: @Audrey Please make your comments an answer

Answer (score 2):

The order isn't wrong; it conforms to the Chicago style. If you want to change it use, say: `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` in your document preamble or biblatex configuration file. To cite the author's last names, use `\citeauthor{GThomson}`. To add a hyperlink, [redefine `\citeauthor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75902).