# Problem with code for fully linked citations with biblatex-apa when citing the same name twice in a row

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am having a problem which is unfortunately quite specific.
Using `biber` and `hyperref`, I was trying to use the author’s name as a `hyperref` reference, too (not only the year) which is similar to `bibtex`/`natbib`.
In general, I think it looks quite nice but there is a problem when trying to reference the same author twice in a row:
[image]

What I would like to have when citing the same authors twice is the same output as in 4) but using `\parencite` or `\textcite` instead of `\citeauthor` and then `\citeyear`.

My code for producing the output above:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bib.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\input{biberhyperlink.tex}

\begin{document}

1) First citations \parencite{Meltzer.Richard.1981} work quite nicely \parencite{Facchini.2018}.

2) However, when citing one author \parencite{Meltzer.Richard.1981} a second time in a row \parencite{Meltzer.Richard.1983}, it does not.

3) \textcite{Meltzer.Richard.1981} and \textcite{Meltzer.Richard.1983} does not work properly either.

4) \citeauthor{Meltzer.Richard.1981} (\citeyear{Meltzer.Richard.1981}) and \citeauthor{Meltzer.Richard.1983} (\citeyear{Meltzer.Richard.1983}) would work as a workaround.

\end{document}
```

Where the `biberhyperlink.tex` file defines the modified functions. I took them from other tex stackexchange questions ([hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/) and [hyperlinking author names in biblatex when using \citeauthor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75902/)) as noted below. I would guess there is a mistake but cannot figure it out myself:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{ \usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75902/hyperlinking-author-names-in-biblatex-when-using-citeauthor
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

For reproduction purposes, this is my `bib` file `Bib.bib`:

```
@article{Facchini.2018,
 author = {Facchini, Francois},
 year = {2018},
 title = {{What Are the Determinants of Public Spending? An Overview of the Literature}}
}
@article{Meltzer.Richard.1981,
 author = {Meltzer, Allan H. and Richard, Scott F.},
 year = {1981},
 title = {{A Rational Theory of the Size of Government}}
}
@article{Meltzer.Richard.1983,
 author = {Meltzer, Allan H. and Richard, Scott F.},
 year = {1983},
 title = {{Tests of a Rational Theory of the Size of Government}}
}
```

If there is no solution to this problem, I would have to use the workaround shown in 4) but obviously, I would prefer a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1687/35864) was written for `style=authoryear,`. It simply does not work with `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa,`.

For `biblatex-apa` I suggest the approach shown in [BibLaTeX Colors And Links Only The Year Not The Rest Of The Citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536353/35864). <sub>This answer previously contained an MWE with code for v9.14 of `biblatex-apa`. To avoid spreading outdated code I decided to remove it here. Please refer to [BibLaTeX Colors And Links Only The Year Not The Rest Of The Citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536353/35864) for an MWE.</sub>

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! One additional question I did not specifically ask for in the original post: What if I still wanted to use the `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` commands as linked citations in addition to your code?
Example:
`\item \citeauthor{Meltzer.Richard.1981}'s (\citeyear{Meltzer.Richard.1981}) model shows\dots`

Comment: @FF0497 Semantically, `\citeyear` is the wrong command here (but `biblatex-apa` uses a slightly unusual definition, which means that it actually does the right thing here). You should use `\parencite*`. (Answer updated with the code for those commands.)

Comment: I am sorry for adding yet another layer to this question but what if I also wanted have the following: "y is determined by x (shown e. g. by Meltzer and Richard, 1981)", with linked citations. With your code, I would get double brackets: "y is determined by x (shown e. g. by Meltzer and Richard (1981))"