# Repeated citations – same author, same paragraph- name doesn’t show – biblatex apa

Tags: biblatex, multiple-citations, apa7

I’m a newcomer to LaTeX.
Everytime that I cite the same author more than once in the same paragraph, in the second citation, the name of the author doesn’t show, only the date: “Bla bla Brown et al. (1998) says bla bla bla. 1998 also says bla bla bla”.
I’ve tried to change some options in the biblatex package, but it didn’t work.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Tks!
Follow below the MWE

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
        style=apa,
        backend=biber,
        ]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}

@article{Brown1998a,
    abstract = {This article reviews the laws and re- lated issues surrounding the gathering and use of personal information by the insurance pro- fession. We exatnine the applicability of these laws to the insurance industry and conclude the article by exploring the issue of self regu- lation as a means to deal with these issues.},
    author = {Brown, Daniel J. and Gammill, Linda and Meintjes, Riaan and Nielson, Norma L. and Seville, Mary Alice},
    doi = {10.1111/j.1540-6296.1998.tb00070.x},
    issn = {10981616},
    journal = {Risk Management and Insurance Review},
    keywords = {Privacy,insurance,regulation,self-regulation},
    month = {jan},
    number = {2},
    pages = {16--34},
    title = {{Privacy and threat of regulation}},
    url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1111/j.1540-6296.1998.tb00070.x},
    volume = {1},
    year = {1998}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.50cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{ \usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
{\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
{\ifbool{cbx:parens}
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
    {}%
    \multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy 
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Bla bla \textcite{Brown1998a} says bla bla bla. \textcite{Brown1998a} also says bla bla bla\par


\printbibliography[title={References}]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code used for full linking of citations is not compatible with `biblatex-apa` (it was written with `style=authoryear,` in mind [see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1687/35864] and will already produce weird output for `style=authoryear-comp,`). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/602824/35864 for a better way to make `biblatex-apa` fully linked.

Comment: Tks a lot for your help!