# biblatex with natbib and hyperref packages in apa style: hyperlink does not cover the complete citation field!

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing, natbib

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-apa}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=blue,colorlinks=true,linktocpage,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\citep{A1}

\citet{A2}

\printbibliography

\fussy
\end{document}
```

and these are the contents of the .bib file:

```
@article{A1,
  author = "Wayne, J.",
  title = "{Without volume...}",
  journal = "Journal A",
  volume = "",
  number = "Y",
  pages = "1-2",
  year = "0000",
  doi  = "10.1007/...",
  url  = ""
}

@article{A2,
  author = "Lee, B.",
  title = "{With volume...",
  journal = "Journal B",
  volume = "X",
  number = "Y",
  pages = "3-4",
  year = "0000",
  doi  = "",
  url  = "https://..."
}
```

As you see, I do not get hyperlinks over the complete citation field (author + year + brackets). What would be the most efficient solution to address this issue?

Comment: Full linking can be pretty painful to implement. For `biblatex-apa` I suggest https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/602824/35864.

Comment: **@moewe**: thanks a lot! I presume the link you provided contains the state-of-the-art solution to the problem. I will see if it works for me. Still, given the extensive workarounds, I might consider using `authoryear` or other styles. Since APA is quite standardly used, I also wonder when the biblatex developers will offer a more synthetic solution to the problem for end-users..............

Comment: Well, `biblatex`'s standard `authoryear` also only links the year. The problem is that a uniform solution that works well for all styles and all edge cases is surprisingly tricky.

Comment: one problem is that citations can also have the form `Smith (2010, 2012)` and how do you want the link there? What should point to the 2010 book and what to 2012?

Comment: **@Ulrike**: the hyperlink should work just as it works for authoryear in bibtex. I guess ``Smith (2010, 2012)`` appears completely hyperlinked, with each year pointing to the appropriate reference. Same goes for ``Smith et al. (2010, 2012a, 2012b)``. Don't ask me about the detailed hyperlink structure for such a situation. No clue..............

Comment: **@moewe**: I see..............

Comment: But to which citation should the word "Smith" link too? And to which one the opening parenthese, the comma and the closing parenthese? You must have clue what you want here, after all it is your feature request.

Comment: **@moewe**: I implemented this solution `tex.stackexchange.com/q/602824/35864` but the hyperlinks do not include the brackets. Is there any other solution including these?

Comment: **@moewe**: nevermind. I actually just realized that for most (if not for all) citation styles, be it in biblatex or in bibtex, the brackets are never hyperlinked! So, the solution you suggested should be fine. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the way the brackets are printed makes it almost impossible to include them in the link. If you wanted that, you'd have to completely overhaul how the typesetting is done.