# citestyle=authoryear, change delimiter

Tags: biblatex, author-number

Using the `authoryear` style, I want to cite works of two authors as **A & B** and more as **A, et al.**, while listing authors as **a A, b B and c C** in the bibliography. Also, the whole citation should be a hyperlink, instead of just the year.

To that end I redefined the `cite` macro:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{\printtext[bibhyperref]
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
            {\iffieldundef{label}
                {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
                {\printfield{label}}\setunit{\addspace}}
            {\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{ \& }%
             \printnames[][-\ifnumgreater{\value{listtotal}}{2}{1}{2}]{labelname}%
            \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
        \iffieldundef{labelyear}{}{\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}
    {\printfield{shorthand}}}}
```

Is there a more robust way to do this, some options I missed, or a CBX that does this already?

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. For me `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames` work as expected. Please provide a complete minimal working example.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't looking at the output of `\cite` but at `\usebibmacro{cite}`.

Comment: For your other question see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear-biblatex-1-4b