# LyX, classicthesis, Mendeley: Citing a web page

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, urls, apa-style, classicthesis

I use Mendeley to organize my Literature and to build the `.bib` file. I also use LyX and the classicthesis template to write my Master's Thesis. Now I want to reference a web page. Using `apalike` as citation style, I miss the `URL` as well as the `Accessed on` information in my bibliography.

As far as I understand it, `apalike` is not able to handle URL's with date accessed. Is there a simple way to include this information into the bibliography? Also, I am open for alternative (but similar!) reference styles, if other solutions are complex.

(Before using LyX and classicthesis I was handling my bibliography with biblatex and biber (which was a perfect solution for me), but as far as I know this is not possible in LyX. Am I right?)

Comment: You can use `biblatex` with LyX. No problem.  But why did you switch to a system that limits you?

Comment: Sorry, the `biblatex` problem was related to `classicthesis`. I read something about `classicthesis` loading `natbib`, which leads to being stuck with natbib, I guess.
I switched to `classicthesis` because I like the template and to LyX since I find it a lot easier to write formulas.

Comment: Kick `natbib`out. Simple as that ;-) `classicthesis` is known for its odd implementation. You can comment out parts if you want. Feel free to do so.

Comment: How would I do that? Replacing the lines `\PassOptionsToPackage{authoryear}{natbib}` and `\usepackage{natbib}` by `\usepackage{biblatex}` and additionally changing the style in LyX to `biblatex` causes a bunch of errors.  

Namely: LaTeX Errors: "\bibhang already defined."; "\citename already defined"; "\bibfont already defined"; "\Citeauthor already defined".  

biblatex Errors: "Incompatible package 'backref'"; "Incompatible package 'natbib'"; "'\bibliographystyle' invalid".  

Can I get rid of these by simply deleting related lines and using biblatex built-in features instead?

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to the very first line of your document. At the bottom of the log file it will be, check if package `natbib` is still there. If yes, it is loaded at another place. You will need multiple runs, since biblatex finds some natbib remains in the helper files. be patient ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from deleting all `natbib` and `backref` related lines in `classicthesis-config.tex`, it is necessary to train LyX to handle biblatex. This can be done following [this manual entry](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex).

Specifically for `classicthesis`it seems to be useful to read [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear-biblatex-1-4b) as it shows how to color more than only the year.