# hyperlink the whole citation call-out not only the year

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I am using the following packages and if I cite something with `\textcite` or `\parencite` it only cross-referencing the year to the corresponding entry in the bibliography. I saw in some papers that they extended this up to the whole citation and not only to the year. how can i do this too? E.g. Muster and Mann ([1990](http://abc.com)) => but i want => [Muster and Mann (1990)](http://abc.com)

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear-ibid,citestyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear-biblatex-1-4b help?

Comment: [Hyperref: linkg full citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/588801)