# Highlight/Link Author and Year in Citation

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, hyperref, citing, thesis

I'm currently modifying the Masters/Doctoral Thesis template found [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis). However, it only highlights the year in a citation like (Smith 2016). I would like both "Smith" and "2016" to be part of the link. I have added a MWE below. It includes the main tex file, the cls file and the bib file. What should be changed?

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{adam.bib}

\begin{document}

This is in \cite{smith2016}.

\end{document}
```

**MastersDoctoralThesis.cls**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\newcommand{\classname}{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\ProvidesClass{\classname}[2015/11/08 v1.2 LaTeXTemplates.com]
\providecommand{\baseclass}{book}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\LoadClass{\baseclass}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=0,
    hypertexnames=false,
    colorlinks=true, 
    citecolor=blue, 
    linkcolor=blue, 
    urlcolor=blue, 
    pdfstartview={FitV},
    unicode,
    breaklinks=true,
}
\endinput
```

**adam.bib**

```
@article{smith2016,
    author={John Smith},
    year={2016}
}
```

PDF Output

[image]

Comment: It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: Thanks. I've added an MWE. These files should all compile on another machine

Comment: See [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864)

Comment: Thanks @moewe. Can I put that in my cls file, or does it have to go in main.tex?

Comment: You can put that in your `.cls` file if you wish, but then you need to make sure that `biblatex` is loaded. Note also that this exact solution will only works absolutely smoothly with the `authoryear` style. It can also go into the preamble of your `.tex` file.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to keep my main.tex file clean, and used primarily for organizing the doc. It's a Masters thesis, and uses a separate tex file for each chapter. Will that change anything?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, I don't think. It can definitely go into the preamble of your (main) document. Whether it should go into a `.cls` depends on what your `.cls` is supposed to do. If it is just for this (and maybe a few other) special documents, than it is fine I suppose; if you want to make the `.cls` re-usable (with other bibliography styles) and allow for more flexibility, moving the code there might not be that good an idea after all.

Comment: Let me know how it worked out for you and if we can close this question as a duplicate of [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864).

Comment: I'm having trouble with this. I keep getting the error "Option clash for package biblatex."

Comment: That suggests you are loading `biblatex` twice (i.e. you have `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}` twice in total), load it only once.

Comment: The content you are stating to be `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` is not the file. Please see the license at the beginning of the class file.

Comment: @moewe I got rid of usepackage{biblatex} in main.tex, and in the cls file just have \RequirePackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}. It compiles, but appears as '(smith2016)', the cite key, rather than the proper format.

Comment: If you load `\RequirePackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}` instead of `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}` as you did before you are requesting the Biber back-end and are not using BibTeX any more, you need to adapt your compilation sequence please read [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864), [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Please note that as Johannes commented from a license point of view you must not change the `.cls` file without changing its name. I would also be against moving `biblatex` code (and even the call to `\usepackage{biblatex}`) to a multi-purpose `.cls` such as this, if you insist on keeping your preamble short (why?) you can externalise it to a personal `.tex` or `.sty` file you can later load. But don't change the `.cls` file.

Comment: Any news here? Does the solution linked to above work for you now? Or did any other problems creep up?

Comment: Sorry, I've been traveling. I will tackle this this afternoon and report back.

Comment: I moved the code to my main.tex file. This gets rid of the errors. However, the citations are still showing up as the cite key, e.g. "smith2016" rather than being formatted.

Comment: Got things up and running! I guess I hadn't compiled my bibtex file in the current setup. I had thought TexStudio does that automatically. This question helped. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number