# bibliography of bookinbook -- the missing author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Try the following MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-comp,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-bookinarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{plato:complete,
    Author = {Plato},
    Editor = {John M. Cooper},
    Keywords = {Primary Source},
    Location = {Indianapolis},
    Publisher = {Hacket Publishing Company},
    Title = {Complete Works},
    Year = {1997}}
@bookinbook{plato:dialogue,
    Author = {Plato},
    Crossref = {plato:complete},
    Pages = {156--191},
    Title = {Dialogue},
    Titleaddon = {\bibstring{bytranslator} Donald J. Zeyl}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
These are the complete works: \cite{plato:complete}. They contain the following text: \cite{plato:dialogue}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It gives this result:

[image: missing authorname]

Is this result really intentional? I.e. do we really want the name "Plato" **not** to be printed again before "*Complete Works*" in the bibliography entry of the dialogue? Should it not better be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is not to print the `bookauthor` if it coincides with the `author` (see `biblatex.def`)

```
\newbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {}
    {\printnames{bookauthor}}}
```

Just add

```
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{\printnames{bookauthor}}
```

to your preamble and the `bookauthor` will always be shown.

Comment: completely unrelated: do we have a question to add for "Only year, not author and year are hyperlinked" qestion? Can you add it to [Often referenced questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2428) Stumbled into this again because of http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=27124

Comment: @Johannes_B My go-to answer is [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864), but there are a few other questions and answers about the same thing on this site. Your LC post might well be [Highlight/Link Author and Year in Citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292086/35864). I'm a bit hesitant to add this question to the often referenced ones because it is very specific about one style (the general idea is applicable elsewhere, but the implementation details can differ greatly).

Comment: Freaking crossposts. Please note, that the cls files is under LPPL 1.3 an should not be changed without changing the name. Thanks for spotting that one and thanks for answering questions on goLaTeX as well.