# apacite-like commands in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

My document used to use bibtex with the package `apacite`, where I used the commands `\cite` and `\citeA` to create citations of the form `(Author, Year)` and `Author (Year)` respectively.

For various reasons I had to switch from bibtex to biblatex. I load it with `\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}`.

I am trying to figure out how to do the same in biblatex:

1. When I use `\parencite` I get a similar effect to apacite's `\cite`, but the PDF link (hyperref) is only created for the year. I would like both the author and the year to have a hyperref link to the bibliography. How do I do that?
2. How do I do something like `\citeA`? I can "fake it" by using two commands like `\citeauthor{key} (\citeyear{key})` but it's cleaner (and has other advantages) to use only one cite command (and again, `\citeauthor` doesn't seem to generate a hyperref link).

Comment: `\citeA` is probably `\textcite`. For the links thing see [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864).

Comment: One problem is that `biblatex-apa` is a compressed style, try to cite `\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c}` from `biblatex-examples.bib`. Which of the two works would you like the link from "Knuth" to go to?

Comment: `\textcite` was exactly the thing, I don't know how I missed it in the docs... Regarding the compressed style, good point, but the other answer you linked to solved my problem. Thank you very much :) If you write your first comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of `apacite`'s `\citeA` in `biblatex` is `\textcite`.

(And you are absolutely right that one should avoid faking such a command by putting together several `\cite...`s into one macro, in `biblatex` it is often not much harder to define a real cite command. And in this case it happens that the command is already there.)

Answer (score 1):

I use APA and have found following to work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Bibliography APA 6th edition - norwegian
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,language=norsk,natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{norsk}{norsk-apa}
    \addbibresource{Bibliotek.bib}
%-----------------------------
\begin{document}

\section{biblatex apa}
\textcite{Adler1989}, \parencite{Adler1989}.

%-----------------------------
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

...with the following Bibliotek.bib

```
@Book{Adler1989,
  Title                    = {{T}he {S}tudy of {O}rchestration. 2ed},
  Author                   = {Adler, Samuel},
  Publisher                = {New York: WW Norton and Company},
  Year                     = {1989}
}
```

Output
[image: biblatex test]

Comment: Note that your `.bib` file can be `biblatex`-ified further. The edition should not go to the `title`, but to `edition`: `title = {{T}he {S}tudy of {O}rchestration}, edition = {2},`. Also the location of the publisher goes to the `location` field and the "and" in the name should be protected: `location = {New York}, publisher = {WW Norton {and} Company},`.