# Add "'s" to an author's name in a citation call-out, BibLaTex plus hyperref (possessive/genitive "'s")

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I'm using biblatex and want to add an 's to an author's name when using the command `\textcite{}`. The "problem" is that I already adjusted the command so that `\textcite` is printed as a complete hyperref. See the code down below. Is there an easy way to implement a solution to my problem? I only found some posts on the theme that were quite old and was hoping there now exists a more smooth solution.

I already tried to create a new command with:

```
\newcommand{\possessivecite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}
```

But how can I combine it with the following so the hyperref is still intact?

```
 % Citation
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=2}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}}}


\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
  }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}
```

Comment: Are you using bibtex or biblatex? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using biblatex. I've corrected the mistake.

Comment: You still do not offer sufficient information as to how we could help you. For example, which style do you use? `biblatex-chicago` offers a `\gentextcite` out of the box.

Comment: Did your `possessivecite` came from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22279/105447? If so, why were the other answers not sufficient for you?

Comment: 1. `\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}` 2. Yes, it came from tex.stackexchange.com/a/22279/105447. Maybe, it is sufficient, but I couldn't manage to connect the solution to hyperref, so that it's displayed as a link. And I thought maybe there is a solution more straight forward. I will check out `\gentextcite`.

Comment: The other answers work with hyperlinks, you only have to load `hyperref` (as I assume you already do). If you don't have a really, really old biblatex version, take the care to use Psychonaut's version of Audrey's answer.

Comment: It would greatly help me to investigate your problem if you could add a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to your question that I can just copy, paste and compile. Ideally that MWE would show the code you have posted already in context. You could also show how Psychonaut's answer did not work for you.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299050/105447

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following combination of [Psychonaut's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/22603/psychonaut) [answer to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307461/35864) [Author name of \textcite as possessive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22273/35864) (with minor modifications applied by me, the answer was based on [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22337/35864) by Audrey) and [Audrey's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey) [answer to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27107/35864) [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864) works a treat for me

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Just for demo
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
  }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname:poss}{% Based on labelname from biblatex.def
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefixi}
         {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}{'s}{}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}{#1's}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{#1}'s}
\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{#1's}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{shorthand}{shorthand:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{citetitle:poss}%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{label}{label:poss}}}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscite}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcite}
\newrobustcmd*{\Posscite}{\bibsentence\posscite}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscites}{%
  \posscitealias%
  \textcites}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\textbf{Single citations}

Filler text \posscite{aristotle:poetics}. Filler text \posscite{kant:ku} \\
Filler text \posscite[See][23]{aristotle:poetics}.
Filler text \posscite[1--10]{kant:ku}. \\
\posscite{aristotle:poetics} and \posscite{kant:ku}.
\posscite[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics} and \textcite[10]{kant:ku}. \\
Filler text.\posscite[23]{aristotle:poetics} Filler text.\posscite[1--10]{aristotle:rhetoric}
Filler text.\footnote{\smartcite[10--15]{companion}}

\textbf{Unqualified citation lists}

\posscite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscite[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscite[10--15]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscite[e.g.][10--15]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscite[See][for example]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}

\textbf{Qualified citation lists}

\posscites{aristotle:poetics}{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscites(See)(){aristotle:poetics}[cf.][]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscites(See)()[10]{aristotle:poetics}[10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscites(See)()[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscites(See)()[e.g.][10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\posscites(See)()[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric}

\textbf{Mix of qualified and unqualified citation lists}

\posscites(See)()[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics}[10]{bertram,companion} \\
\posscites[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}[10]{companion} \\
\posscites[10]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}[cf.][]{bertram} \\
\posscites[15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{bertram,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]