# Change color of comma in citation

Tags: biblatex

I customised my biblatex citation to look exactly how I want them to look, except the comma in `\citep` should have the same color as the link. (It does not matter if the comma is actually inside the hyperlink or if it will just have the same color)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    natbib=true,            
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Thesis.bib}

% modify \cite to add parenthesis around the year
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}{%
        \ifthenelse{%
            \ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}%
        }{%
            \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
        }{%
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
        }%
%       \ifentrytype{online}{\addspace \textendash\addspace\usebibmacro{title}}{%
            \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
%       }%  
    }%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
    {   
%   \multicitedelim
    \textcitedelim
    }
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citep}[\mkbibparens]{%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}%
}{%
    \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}{%
        \ifthenelse{%
            \ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}%
        }{%
            \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
        }{%
            \printtext[bibhyperref]{% Apply citation link to bibmacro output
            \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
            \printnames[labelname_p]{labelname}%
            \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
        }
        }%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
    }{%
        \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
    }%
}{%
%   \multicitedelim%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}
    {\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
}{%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}               
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,            
    citecolor=red,
}

\begin{filecontents}{Thesis.bib}
@ARTICLE{2019arXiv190606091W,
       author = {{Wolf}, C. and {Langer}, C. and {Montes}, F. and {Pereira}, J. and
         {Ong}, W. -J. and {Poxon-Pearson}, T. and {Ahn}, S. and {Ayoub}, S. and
         {Baumann}, T. and {Bazin}, D.},
        title = "{Constraining the Neutron Star Compactness: Extraction of the $^{23}$Al($p,\gamma$) Reaction Rate for the $rp$-Process}",
      journal = {arXiv e-prints},
     keywords = {Nuclear Experiment, Astrophysics - Instrumentation and Methods for Astrophysics, Astrophysics - Solar and Stellar Astrophysics, Nuclear Theory},
         year = "2019",
        month = "Jun",
          eid = {arXiv:1906.06091},
        pages = {arXiv:1906.06091},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {1906.06091},
 primaryClass = {nucl-ex},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019arXiv190606091W},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{2019arXiv190606091W}  

\citep{2019arXiv190606091W}

\citep[this text][and this text should remain black]{2019arXiv190606091W}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered including the outer parentheses (and, by extension, everything they encase) into a single hyperlink? That way, you wouldn't have to worry about the treatment of the comma that separates the `author` and `year` fields. (Aside: I think that the separator comma is unnecessary and shouldn't be there.) Making the parentheses in the parenthetic-style citation call-out part of the hyperlink would also restore visual parity with the text-style citation call-out.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your comment! The outer parentheses should not be colored. I also don't want to color everything, for example if there are two citations, the "and" between them should remain black. I only want to color this comma between the author and the year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code applies the link to entire citation label consisting of author names, comma and year. Hence, the comma is also coloured. I used my `biblatex-ext` style and code similar to [Macro For Hyperlinked Citation in Parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299050/35864) to simplify the complete setup.

The idea is to add the parentheses around the year with `\DeclareInnerCiteDelims` and the links by copying the original cite macro with `\letbibmacro` and re-wrapping it in a link.

Note that `\letbibmacro` needs a recent version of `biblatex`. (The version currently run on Overleaf is too old for `\letbibmacro` and also does not come with `biblatex-ext`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  style=ext-authoryear,
  natbib=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=red,
}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
\DeclareDelimFormat[cite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\letbibmacro{saved:cite}{cite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \usebibmacro{saved:cite}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\parencite{sigfridsson}

\parencite[this text][and this text should remain black]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really only want to colour the comma, you would normally use

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[cite,parencite]{nameyeardelim}{\textcolor{red}{\addcomma\space}}
```

but your redefinition of `\citep` uses `\nameyeardelim` and not the context-sensitive `\printdelim{nameyeardelim}`, so you may as well replace

```
\setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
```

with

```
\setunit{\textcolor{red}{\nameyeardelim}}%
```

Note that you will have to add a forgotten `%` after the following closing curly brace (the `}` in the next line) to avoid unwanted white space (that space is automatically removed by `\addcomma`, but can not be removed by `\textcolor{red}{\addcomma}`).

Comment: There is only one word I can think of for your answer: perfect!