# Edit the link span of a \cite

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing, biber, links

I am using biblatex with backend=biber and hyperref package.

In order to control the cite link color, I use

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{065F8F}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
         citecolor=mycolor,
         linkcolor=black,
         urlcolor=mycolor}
```

For the biblatex package, I configure style

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style = authoryear,
    citestyle = authoryear-ibidem,
    hyperref = true,
    ...
]
```

When I now use the \cite command, it renders something like

Albrecht and Lee, 2012

where you must imagine the 2012 in blue and the rest in black. How can I edit the \cite command so that the complete reference (including the author name) is a link and therefore blue?

Comment: Even though your question is clear and, as far as I can see, well defined, it would be easier for the folks to play with your problem, and thus answer it, if you supplied a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), which illustrates the issue.

Comment: A solution will definitely depend on the style you use. Do you use `style=authoryear` or something else? Do you apply any modifications to that style?

Comment: See [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864)

Comment: OK I will try to provide an MWE. Inserted Moewes suggestion.

Comment: `authoryear-ibidem` is not a style I know, the standard style is called `authoryear-ibid`, do you mean that? Note that in that case `style = authoryear, citestyle = authoryear-ibid,` is equivalent to `style = authoryear-ibid,`.

Comment: yes I do mean that.