# how can I change round bracket to square bracket using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
\setlength{\bibhang}{5\p@}%
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{3.5\p@}%
%\setlength{\biblabelsep}{-10\p@}%
\def\bibfont{\footnotesize}%
%\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}
%%%
\newlength{\bibleftadd}%
\setlength{\bibleftadd}{-5\p@}%
%%
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\vspace{-2\p@}\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}\list%
     {}%
     {\setlength{\topsep}{\z@}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\bibleftadd}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

This is for test \citet{antibayes} and \citep{pijnacker2}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

%%content of test.bib%

```
@incollection{antibayes,
Address = {The Press},
Author = {G. Author1 and K. Author2 and M. Author3},
Booktitle = {The {U}niversity},
Date-Added = {2014-02-06 15:25:25 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-06 15:28:59 +0100},
Editor = {M. Editor1 and P. Editor2},
Publisher = {The {U}niversity},
Title = {The {C}ognitive {I}nterface},
Year = {2021}}

@article{pijnacker2,
Author = {J. Author4 and B. Author5 and M. Author6 and J. Author7 and P. Author8},
Date-Added = {2014-02-06 15:14:32 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-06 15:17:39 +0100},
Journal = {Journal of {T}ext},
Number = {2},
Pages = {471--480},
Title = {Study},
Volume = {23},
Year = {2010}}
```

And the output is:

[image]

I want to change the brackets from `round` to `square`, please advise how to fix this....

I meant the similar option which are available with `natbib.sty` by `\setcitestyle{square}` and `\setcitestyle{round}`...

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387281/how-to-use-biblatex-with-square-brackets-and-hyperref

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16765/35864. In general I would not use this trick as there are slightly more robust solutions for the standard styles. But for `biblatex-chicago` this is probably the quickest solution.