# Disable hyperlink just for textcite

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I just want to remove hyperlink for `textcite`. This a MWE from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear-biblatex-1-4b):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Just for demo
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
  }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\textbf{Single citations}

Filler text \parencite{aristotle:poetics}. Filler text \parencite{kant:ku} \\
Filler text \parencite[See][23]{aristotle:poetics}.
Filler text \parencite[1--10]{kant:ku}. \\
\textcite{aristotle:poetics} and \textcite{kant:ku}.
\textcite[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics} and \textcite[10]{kant:ku}. \\
Filler text.\footcite[23]{aristotle:poetics} Filler text.\footcite[1--10]{aristotle:rhetoric}
Filler text.\footnote{\smartcite[10--15]{companion}}

\textbf{Unqualified citation lists}

\textcite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcite[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcite[10--15]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcite[e.g.][10--15]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\parencite[See][for example]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}

\textbf{Qualified citation lists}

\textcites{aristotle:poetics}{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcites(See)(){aristotle:poetics}[cf.][]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcites(See)()[10]{aristotle:poetics}[10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcites(See)()[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\textcites(See)()[e.g.][10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric} \\
\parencites(See)()[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{aristotle:rhetoric}

\textbf{Mix of qualified and unqualified citation lists}

\textcites(See)()[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics}[10]{bertram,companion} \\
\textcites[e.g.][]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}[10]{companion} \\
\textcites[10]{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}[cf.][]{bertram} \\
\textcites[15]{aristotle:poetics}[cf.][10]{bertram,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, this is not a MWE, because `biblatex-examples.bib` is an external file which we do not have access to.  You can use `filecontents` package within your example.  Also, for it to be *minimal* you only need to have a few `\textcite` commands in the document (and maybe one or two `\parencite` etc.).

Comment: To clarify: you want to disable hyperlinking for *only* `\textcite`?  But other linking commands, such as `\parencite`, `\textcites`, `\parencites`, etc. should retain hyperlinks?

Comment: @whatisit Yes. I just want this for `\textcite`.

Comment: @whatisit biblatex-examples.bib is in every tex system and is a perfect bib for examples (much better than bib entries with filecontents which only add more junk to my test folder).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oops, yes you are correct!  I actually was unaware and assumed it was a local file.

Comment: @user2991243 Would it be enough to remove the boarder indicating the hyperlink or does the link has to be totally removed?

Comment: @samcarter I think removing the boarder is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to just redefine the `bibhyperref` field format that usually sets the links locally for `textcite`. There are several ways to do this (for example with  [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch/)), but since the MWE already uses the `\savebibmacro`–`\restorebibmacro` approach we might as well use that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Just for demo
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Remove all links
  \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
  \usebibmacro{textcite}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{sigfridsson}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the MWE: The citations show "Sigfridsson et al. (1998)" without link and a fully-linked "Sigfridsson et al. 1998"]

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much for the image upload.

Comment: You're welcome! In the last few months there seems to be an increase of problems with image uploads -- it starts to get annoying ...

Comment: @samcarter I'm pretty sure this is my internet connection, though. Usually it works fine, but I'm away from my flat.