# How to change all the BibTeX \cite{} commands to BibLaTeX parenthetical citation commands when switching from pure vanilla BibTeX to BibLaTEX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, apa-style

**Context**

I have a thesis of over 340 pages written using LaTeX and one massive BibTeX file for references (.bib). The thesis employs the `\cite{}` command for all in-text citations, there is a zillion of these scattered in all the chapters. 
I know there are other questions tackling transforming from BibTeX + natbib to BibLaTeX & vice versa.

When using natbib + BibTeX TO BibLaTeX, the solution would be to add the option `natbib=true` but this relies on using already `\citet` and `\citep` throughout the document not the traditional `\cite{}` if I am not mistaken.

Anyway my context is different. I only have the `\cite{}` command used. This is why I called it the pure Vanilla BibTeX `\cite{}` command - no other packages used. I wanted to change my citation style to an `author-year` style so I moved to BibLaTeX and used the `apa` style. The previous citation style was numerical: `[1-3]`

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

The first problem encountered is that all `\cite{}` instances gave me the traditional non-parenthetical citations which I do not want. Ex: `Cabanier et al., 2014` instead of `(Cabanier et al., 2014)`.

That can be solved by changing every `\cite{}` to `\autocite{}` or `\parencite{}` but that would be cumbersome to do for all the instances. I have thousands of instances.

The second problem encountered is that only part of citation i.e. the year is clickable not the whole citation. I am using also `hyperref`.

**Question**

Apologies! I am new to BibLaTeX, any suggestions on how to solve both problems, are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd not use `style=apa,citestyle=authoryear`. `style=apa` is a full-blown implementation of APA style for `biblatex`, whereas `authoryear` is 'just' a simple author-year style. I'd use `style=apa` only if APA style or something extremely close to APA style is required. If `citestyle=authoryear` is appropriate, chances are you don't actually want APA style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every good text editor should have a search-and-replace feature.

It should be quite safe to replace

- `\cite[` with `\autocite[` and
- `\cite{` with `\autocite{`.

Make a backup of your file, then perform the search-and-replace, compile and scrutinise the output carefully.

In theory you could just take the definition of `\parencite` from the `.cbx` and replace `\parencite` with `\cite` to redefine `\cite` to give the same output as `\parencite`. But that feels like cheating, is inconsistent with usual behaviour, prevents you from using the real `\cite` should you want to and may have some subtle stumbling blocks that mean that the output is slightly different (think delimiter contexts).

---

The link thingy is a commonly mentioned issue, have a look at [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864) and linked questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I  hoped to find solutions such as having some sort of a redefinition of \cite{} command to behave like \autocite{} or some sort of a macro or some option in the package that I am not aware of. But your solution will do it also. I do believe a good addition to the package is an option to change the behaviour of \cite{}. I hope I can contact the BibLaTeX developpers, maybe this might be interesting to add as a feature. Thx again

Comment: @HB87 You can already change the behaviour of `\cite`. And as I mentioned it would quite easily be possible to redefine `\cite` to behave more or less like `\parencite`. I did not explore this in more depth because I believe it is the wrong approach: The set of citation commands in `biblatex` is quite sensible and it is a very good idea to use the high-level `\autocite` command. (Plus it would be confusing if `\cite` behaved differently in your document) The search-and-replace job should be easily done in most editors and is not complicated or tricky, so I see little point in not going for it.

Comment: Thx a lot for all the help