# link author and year in citation label - style=ext-authoryear

Tags: biblatex

I would like to know how the author in the citation label can be part of the hyperlink as well. I changed the style of the reference by hand. The following MWE shows the package I used.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Labov1972,
        Address = {Philadelphia},
        Author = {William Labov},
        Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
        Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
        Year = {1972}}

    @book{Chomsky1957,
        Address = {The Hague},
        Author = {Noam Chomsky},
        Publisher = {Mouton},
        Title = {Syntactic Structures},
        Year = {1957}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Bibliothek
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% style einstellen
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear,
backref=true,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
articlein=false,
dashed=false,
introcite=plain,
labelalpha=true
]{biblatex}


%% Style Schriftum direkt aus dem Manual kopiert
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bbx@introcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{bbx@introcite}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\quad}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}


% Bei mehreren Autoren et al.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} 

% Keine Anführungszeichen beim Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{#1}}

%% Style des Verweises im Text
% Eckige Klammern um Autor Jahr
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{[}{]}
% [Autor Jahr] -> [Autor, Jahr]
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    backrefpage={zitiert auf Seite:},
    backrefpages={zitiert auf Seiten:}
}

%% Laden der Bibliothek
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Ende Bibliothek
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

    Text text \cite{Chomsky1957}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In the Screenshot you can see that only the year is included in the link.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a similar strategy as in [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864), but with the new `\letbibmacro` instead of `\restorebibmacro` we can come up with the following MWE.

Note that we also need to stop the `introcite` output from reproducing the link. With a sufficiently up-to-date version of `biblatex-ext`, we can use `\AtIntrocite{\DeclareFieldFormat{linkallcite}{#1}}` for that.

(I removed the comments to make the example more compact and changed one or two small details.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  backref=true,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false,
  articlein=false,
  dashed=false,
  introcite=plain,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bbx@introcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{bbx@introcite}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\quad}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareFieldFormat{linkallcite}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \bibhyperref{#1}%
}
\AtIntrocite{\DeclareFieldFormat{linkallcite}{#1}}

\letbibmacro{cite:orig}{cite}
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
  \printtext[linkallcite]{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:orig}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers    = {{et\,al\adddot}},
  backrefpage  = {zitiert auf Seite:},
  backrefpages = {zitiert auf Seiten:},
}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Text text \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Fully linked "Sigfridsson und Ryde, 1998" citation label.]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly how I want it. Have a nice day!

Comment: @moewe: It was suggested that you might have an opinion on https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60016401#60016401