# Lyx bibliography for link-to-biblography style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx, natbib

I tried many things on here but all failed. I want to do this:

1. Don't put ***Einstein, Albert (1990) "Relativity"*** into footnote. Put in into bibliography section.
2. Make blue-colored hyperlink within the document from ***Einstein (1990)*** to ***Einstein, Albert (1990) "Relativity"***

Choosing ***Document Settings -> Bibliography -> Citation Style -> Biblatex*** resulted in the hyperlink created only on ***1990***, rather than on entire ***Einstein (1990)***.

And maybe this isn't necessary. But to add what I tried and failed: Choosing ***Document Settings -> Bibliography -> Citation Style -> Natbib (BibTeX)*** resulted in an error when converting it to pdf (Though I am not sure if this is correct thing to choose)

Comment: It is possible to generate larger link targets in `biblatex` citations, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864, but I'd just accept that the link target is a little smaller especially with LyX, since adding the required extra code is a bit of a pain (and there are corner cases, where things might not work as expected)

Comment: @moewe  Thank you but I am failing to use Audrey's example on Lyx. I just copy-pasted his code before "\begin{document}"  into the preamble of Lyx file. When I try to convert it to pdf, it says "missing \begin{document}"   and "undefined control sequence"  and "You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode."

Comment: @moewe Oh I added two more lines "\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}"   in Audrey's example, and then now it seems to work. Thank you!