# How to make parentheses part of a clickable citation reference link in hyperref?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, citing, natbib

Currently, my citations look like this (using natbib, author-year, bibtex for bibliography with style as ACM-Reference-Format):

[image]

Is it possible to make the **parentheses in the citation** also part of the link? Such as in the following example:

.

[image]

Comment: You've set tags for two mutually incompatible packages -- `biblatex` and `natbib`. Which one (if any) of these packages do you use to create the bibliography and citation call-outs? Please also tell us if you use bibtex or biber as the external program. And, if you use bibtex, which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: natbib.  I use bibtex I believe.  The style is ACM-Reference-Format

Comment: without a complete example it is quite impossible to answer this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am a big fan of reproducible examples.  However, I am not sure how to add the bibliography as an external file.  I thought the question was simple enough someone would point me to an option in the natbib package, for example.

Comment: Sorry that is a quite bad excuse.  You only need  one bib entry to demonstrate the issue. You can simply add it to the question. Or use an entry from biblatex-examples.bib

Comment: show yor code please

Comment: Berating a user for not knowing how to do something is inappropriate, unbecoming of experts, and not at all welcoming. It's been done to me too and I  do not appreciate it and I'm tired of seeing it here. I apologize to the OP on behalf of the community.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment for I do not have 50 of reputation, but I am pretty sure this is a duplicate of the [this  question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear-biblatex-1-4b) which has a working solution.

Comment: Actually compiling the code shows the brackets are still not part of the hyperlink