# How do I make the entire citation a blue hyperlink

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, biber, overleaf

Currently, I am using the following preamble on overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  

\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=bwl-FU,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} 


\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{ABC}
\date{\today}


\maketitle
\section{Model}
In this context, healthcare utilization has two components that are important in justifying the estimation methods selected \cite{gerdtham1997equity}. 


\printbibliography
\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}


\end{document}
```

And the end result is in the image with the citation where only the year of publication is highlighted.
[image]

What I want out of the citation is the following:

[image]

Is there a way to edit the preamble to make my citations appear as shown in the second image?
Thanks!

Comment: `\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}`  You can have A4 paper size or a 6in by 8in paper size but both at same time?

Comment: Your document stops at `! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.` use biblatex/biber or natbib/bibtex. You can not use natbib and biblatex together

Comment: I have made the edits to the comments but my citations remain the same as in picture 1 of my post.

Comment: Your new file gives `! Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid for 'biblatex'.`   You need to use biblatex commands if using biblatex.  Don't even look at pdf output after an error, it is just a possble debugging tool, not a usable document

Comment: I am using Overleaf and it compiles without error messages if that helps.

Comment: that seems unlikely. you have no red circle at the top with an error count?

Comment: Yes there was one when I included \bibliographystyle{apalike} (which does not work with biblatex) but otherwise I have no error messages.

Comment: as I say an error is an error.  make an error free example and add here before asking about incorrect pdf output. it's not really possible to say anything about why a bibliography is not the correct style on a document that gives an error saying the bibliographystyle command is in error and should not be used

Comment: I have edited the code given in the original sample. It is now error free.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864.