# Biblatex, author-year, square brackets

Tags: biblatex, citing, brackets

I need to customize the author-year citation in `biblatex` for a template at work. Right now `biblatex` cites like this:

> Ruschmeyer u. a. 1995, S. 123

They way I was told it needs to cite is:

> [Ruschmeyer u. a. 1995, S. 123]

This seems pretty simple and I thought it would be done in a second, but after reading through the `biblatex` documentation for the second time, I still don't really have a clue.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

An alternative to lockstep's solution is to redefine the high-level parentheses commands. With the default option setting `parentracker=true`, these are context-sensitive; nested parentheses may be set as brackets, depending on the nesting level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

%\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{parentracker=false}

\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text \parencite[see][59--63]{markey}. \\
Filler text \parencite[see][\pno~59 \parentext{last paragraph}]{markey}. \\
Filler text \parencite[see][\pno~59 \brackettext{last paragraph}]{markey}. \\
\parentext{Filler text \parencite[see][\pno~59 \parentext{last paragraph}]{markey}.} \\
\brackettext{Filler text \parencite[see][\pno~59 \parentext{last paragraph}]{markey}.} \\
\citeauthor{markey} show that this is filler text \parencite*{markey}. \\
\textcite[see][\pno~59 \parentext{last paragraph}]{markey} show that this is filler text. \\
Filler text \autocite{markey}. \\
\citeauthor{markey} show that this is filler text \autocite*{markey}. \\
Filler text.\smartcite[\pno~59 \brackettext{last paragraph}]{markey}
Filler text.\footnote{More filler text \smartcite[see][\pno~59 \brackettext{last paragraph}]{markey}.} \\
\parencites{markey,knuth:ct:b} \\
\textcites{markey,knuth:ct:b} \\
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `\ifcitation`. This answer should become the accepted one.

Comment: And how do I get a bibliography in table style (the names in brackets on the left hand side and the informations about the references on the right hand side?

Comment: @pirad [This post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/4483) might help. If that isn't what you had in mind, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: +1 for the nice solution. Still, I thought 'just' adding some brackets would not be so complicated with the newer biblatex...

Comment: @Alexander Complications arise in parenthesis tracking. If you don't use this feature, the simple solution I first posted should work.

Comment: @Audrey May I see what you wrote in biblatex-examples.bib?

Answer (score 16):

First, if you want brackets or parentheses, you should use `\parencite{}`, instead of `\cite{}`.

By default, this will produce round parentheses () in the author-year citation style. If you want square brackets [] instead, you can create your own `.cbx` file, and the easiest way is to modify an existing one. I provide an example at the end of the post.

(Note: Audrey's solution is simpler than this one, but it did not work when I tried it. This solution worked for me.)

Save the modified cbx file in your working directory as `authoryearbrack.cbx`, and then in your `.tex` file use:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryearbrack]{biblatex}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

That should do it. If you are interested in creating your own `.cbx` files more generally, read on.

In a standard TeX Live distribution, with biblatex installed, you should find all the default biblatex `.cbx` files under `texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx`. For example, `authoryear.cbx` is for the basic author-year citation style, and you'll also find `authoryear-comp.cbx`, `authoryear-ibid.cbx`, etc.

In order to produce the file below, I started with `authoryear.cbx` and did just two things:

1. Changed every occurrence of `\mkbibparens` to `\mkbibbrackets`, and
2. Changed the comments and `ProvidesFile` lines at the top of the file to reflect the new file name.

Here is the modified version of `authoryear.cbx` which uses brackets instead of parentheses, and which you should save as `authoryearbrack.cbx`:

```
% $Id: authoryearbrack.cbx,v 1 anon $

\ProvidesFile{authoryearbrack.cbx}
[\abx@cbxid $Id: authoryearbrack.cbx,v 1 anon $]

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelyear,uniquename,uniquelist,autocite=inline}
\newbool{cbx:parens}

\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
    \setunit{%
      \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
      \addspace\bibopenparen}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
      {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \addspace\bibopenparen}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen}
       {}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
       {\setunit{\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
     \printfield{postnote}\bibcloseparen}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\endinput
```

Comment: What exactly "did not work" in Audrey's solution?

Comment: Taking a closer look at your solution, a) `\bibopenparen`/ `\bibcloseparen` should be replaced with `\bibopenbracket`/`\bibclosebracket` b) the result will closely mirror my answer. ;-) That said, welcome to tex.sx!

Comment: @Steve Did the problem relate to parenthesis tracking? If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make the bibliography section use square brackets as well?  Right now it's like "Einstein (2017). Title"

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Except if I do \textcite, it still uses parentheses instead of square brackets. Any hints on how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks. This works for me except if I do \textcite, I still get the year in parentheses not square brackets.

Any hints aside from doing something tedious like ``according to \citeauthor{machanick2007social} [\citeyear{machanick2007social}]''.

Comment: When I use this I get: “Package biblatex Warning: 'labelyear' option is deprecated. Please use 'labeldateparts' instead.” Fixing this is not a simple search and replace; doing that makes it cite each reference with its title not author-year. Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 9):

The styles of the [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author.</sup> have a feature to change the parentheses around `\parencite` and friends easily.

```
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{⟨cite command⟩}{⟨opening delimiter⟩}{⟨closing delimiter⟩}
```

redefines the outer citation delimiters of `\⟨cite command⟩`.

There is an analogous

```
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{⟨cite command⟩}{⟨opening delimiter⟩}{⟨closing delimiter⟩}
```

for the 'inner' delimiter (the parentheses around the year in `\textcite`).

The bundle has one extended style for each standard style. The default settings are so that the `ext-<standard style>` style can be used as a drop-in replacement of `<standard style>` without changes in output.

To obtain square brackets for `authoryear`'s `\parencite` one would load `ext-authoryear` and issue the following `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims` declaration.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson} -- \parencite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998] – [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998]]

Answer (score 5):

(I suspect that a better solution will turn up.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
    \setunit{%
      \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
      \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
      {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibclosebracket}
       {}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
       {\setunit{\addspace\bibopenbracket}}%
     \printfield{postnote}\bibclosebracket}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{A01}

\parencite{A01}

\autocite{A01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could renew the command in order to introduce the brackets. This is a way to do it:

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand*\cite[1]{[\oldcite{#1}]}
```

Comment: Also that's a bad idea as you should at least use `\mkbibbrackets` or the like.

Comment: While this might be acceptable for other bibliography(citatin packages it is a bad idea for `biblatex`. You will definitely lose the ability to use pre- and postnotes- (i.e. the optional arguments) that way. As TeXnician notes, hard-coding the brackets will make them invisible to `biblatex`'s parentheses tracker, but that is probably not too bad here.

Answer (score 3):

When you just want to but around braces in your cite, use

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\parencite}
```

When you want to add a comma before the year, use

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

For adding the square brackets, see @Audrey's answer.

(Answers taken from the duplicate question [Redefine \cite for brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110015/9075))

When you want to add **hyperlinked names** too, use following solution:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

(Answer based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1690/9075)