# Biblatex authoryear in brackets and with parenthesis around the year

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I use square brackets around my citations (`/parencite`) from the answer to [Biblatex, author-year, square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/biblatex-author-year-square-brackets).
So now I have

> [Doe 1995]

in text. But I would like to have

> [Doe (1995)]

in text. 
The way the bibliography is should not change. It now is like this:

> Doe, J. (1995), ...

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a lot of brackets and braces, but here we go. :-) I suggest to use Audrey's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16792) to the linked question and to add a redefinition of the `cite` bibmacro (namely, to add parentheses to the `cite:labelyear+extrayear` bibmacro).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
%     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}% DELETED
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}% ADDED
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text \parencite[see][59--63]{A01}. \\
Filler text \parencite[see][\pno~59 \parentext{last paragraph}]{A01}. \\
Filler text \parencite[see][\pno~59 \brackettext{last paragraph}]{A01}. \\
\parentext{Filler text \parencite[see][\pno~59 \parentext{last paragraph}]{A01}.} \\
\brackettext{Filler text \parencite[see][\pno~59 \parentext{last paragraph}]{A01}.} \\
\citeauthor{A01} show that this is filler text \parencite*{A01}. \\
\textcite[see][\pno~59 \parentext{last paragraph}]{A01} show that this is filler text. \\
Filler text \autocite{A01}. \\
\citeauthor{A01} show that this is filler text \autocite*{A01}. \\
Filler text.\smartcite[\pno~59 \brackettext{last paragraph}]{A01}
Filler text.\footnote{More filler text \smartcite[see][\pno~59 \brackettext{last paragraph}]{A01}.} \\
\parencites{A01,B02} \\
\textcites{A01,B02} \\

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]