# biblatex authoryear-icomp parenthesis in footnotes and textcite

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, punctuation, parenthesis

By typing

`Some text \autocite[88]{A01}.`

`Now Textcite \textcite[88]{A01}`

I try to achieve the following output:
[image]

Using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39919/biblatex-authoryear-icomp-brackets-around-the-year-in-footnotes/39923#39923) answer, I do get the footnotes right. Unfortunately, there are brackets when using `\textcite`, which I consider bad typography.

[image]

Using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30819/problem-footcite-biblatex/30850#30850) answer, `\textcite` works as expected. However, parenthesis in footnotes now span both year and page number.
[image]

Using one of the rich [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50691/biblatex-authoryear-in-brackets-and-with-parenthesis-around-the-year)  have not brought me closer. Whats left is my MWE.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{A01,        
      author = {Author, A.},
      year = {2001},
      title = {Alpha},
      journaltitle = {A Journal},
      volume = {1},
      number = {1},
    }
    @misc{B02,
      author = {Buthor, B.},
      year = {2002},
      title = {Bravo},
      location = {There},
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

    \textheight=120pt% only for the example

    \begin{document}

    Some text \autocite[88]{A01}.

    Some text \autocite[88]{B02}.

    Some text \autocite[88]{B02}.

    Now Textcite \textcite[88]{A01}

    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

Comment: What about the `comp` features? What should `\autocites[12]{A01}[13]{B02}`, `\autocite[12]{A01,B02}` and `\autocite{A01,B02}` give? If you can drop the "comp" feature, things might get easier code-length wise. And while we're at it: What about the "ibid"? Do you want it `\textcite`-style with the name, or as normally without the name.

Comment: But what about "Knuth 1984, Knuth 1986a, Knuth 1986b", would you want "Knuth 1984,1986a,b" there? (I should have probably said `\autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}` in my comment.)

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Both `comp` and `ibid` would be nice to have, hence me using `icomp`. However, citing as stated above should be priority.

Comment: "Nice to have" doesn't actually say what you think about say "Knuth (1986a), p. 12, (b)" which is what could happen with `icomp`, I imagine. That would probably not be something you find nice, but then do you want "Knuth (1986a,b)" if possible? And what about "ibid" do you want "Knuth (ibid)" or just "ibid"? (I realise that these questions might be annoying, but they are needed to decide which approach to take, the cite macro in `authoryear` takes about 10 lines in `authoryear-icomp` it is 2.5 times that + some helper macros)

Comment: I highly appreciate your efforts. Thank you for asking very specific questions. Your assumptions are right.

"(1984; 1986a,b)" would be ideal for `\textcite{K84}{K86a}{K86b}`. As we usually include page numbers, `\textcite[12]{K84}[13]{K86a}{K86b}` would lead to "(1984, p. 12; 1986a, p. 13; 1986b)".

Using `\autocite[12]{K86a}[13]{K86b}` gives "Knuth (1986a), p. 12; Knuth (1986b), p. 13." in footnotes, which is sufficient.

"ibid" instead of "Knuth (ibid)" meets my faculty requirements, too.
If taken care of the sorting manually, the `comp` feature is not necessary.

Comment: As of now, I got away by using `jurabib`. Old, maybe even deprecated, but does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `authoryear-icomp` with regards to brackets around years is not that simple, so may I interest you in the `\DeclareInnerCiteDelims` feature of my [`biblatex-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)? Simply use the style `style=ext-<yourstyle>` instead of `style=<yourstyle>`. The `ext-...` styles are written so that they can be used as a drop-in replacement of the standard styles.

With `\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}` you wrap the year in `\footcite` (and `\autocite` if it ends up in as a `\footcite` with `autocite=footnote`) in round brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-icomp,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,        
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  location = {There},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=120pt% only for the example

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite[88]{A01}.

Some text \autocite[88]{B02}.

Some text \autocite[88]{B02}.

Now Textcite \textcite[88]{A01}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edited for [name changes in version 0.4](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/7d2e2f1be11f68dcdec62897e1e2afeaa3809e80/CHANGES.md) of `biblatex-ext`.*

If you don't want to use an external package, you will have to modify the `cite` and `cite:postnote` bibmacros as follows

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnameundef{labelname}}
                    or test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{%
             \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
             \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}%
             \bibopenparen}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
             {\ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}
                          and (test {\ifnumequal{\value{multicitecount}}{0}}
                               or test {\iffieldundef{postnote}})}
                {\setunit{\addcomma}%
                 \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
                {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
                 \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
                 \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
             {\printnames{labelname}%
              \setunit{%
                \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
                \printdelim{nameyeardelim}%
                \bibopenparen}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
              \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen
       \global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
  \setunit{}%
  \printtext{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen
       \global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}}%
  \ifbool{cbx:loccit}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}
\makeatother
```