# Redefine \cite for brackets

Tags: biblatex, citing, brackets

**EDIT:** I finally found out how to do it:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}
\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cite}{\parencite}
```

---

The code for square brackets is from this thread: [Biblatex, author-year, square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/biblatex-author-year-square-brackets)
And the renewcommand changes \cite to have the same properties as \parencite

How do I redefine \cite so that there are brackets [] around it?

`\let\[\cite\]=\cite` did not work.

It should look like this: `text bla bla[John Doe, 1990] bla bla bla text more text`
Every functionality in \cite should still be there.

I am using Biblatex `\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}`

EDIT: In my opinion this is not a duplicate. The mentioned question is similiar but I want to use `\cite` and NOT `\parencite` or other types of cite to achieve the following:

Square brackets around the citation and NOT! round brackets as this is the case for `\parencite`. It has to be the `\cite` command because I am working with another program which requires the `\cite` command.

Comment: I looked into this but it has to be `\cite` I can not use `\parencite`

Comment: Add the following to your preamble after loading `biblatex`: `\usepackage{letltxmacro}\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\parencite}`

Comment: If you also want to get the comma between the author and the year, put `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` in your preamble. I will delete my answer below, since it was mainly a reference to the duplicate.

Comment: ok thank you that almost works. how do i get square brackets? I am sorry that I forgot to mention this ...

Comment: Read Audrey's answer to the linked question.

Comment: I read it but there he uses \parencite and other types of cite but not `\cite` which I have to use. I just want `\cite` to citate like `text[John Doe, 2009]` with square brackets and not round brackets

Comment: Try to combine lockstep's solution, for mapping `cite` to `parencite`, with Audrey's solution (giving square brackets). That should work.