# squared bracketed citation in references list

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}` in my document followed by [square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16792/11881) and [full hyperlink](http://covariant.me/notes/biblatex.html#hyperlinks) which gives me this in the document `[MacRae and Pattison 2002]` and this in the references

```
MacRae, K. and J. Pattison (2002). “Home chemotherapy.” In: Nursing Times 98.35, pp. 34–35.
```

How can I get it so that I also have the same squared-bracketed citation in the references please?

Comment: I'm afraid your objective isn't entirely clear (to me at least). Are you looking to prefix the string `[MacRae and Pattison 2002]` to the bibliographic entry? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico; yes, in front of its appropriate entry.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\mkbibparens[1]{[#1]}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}

\begin{document}

foo~\parencite{IEEEexample:masterstype}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, in this example it should be [Karnik A,1999], that is what I'm looking for

Comment: @boudiccas Where should it be "[Karnik A, 1999]", because from your question (where you had "[MacRae and Pattison 2002]", no first names, not even a comma) I get the expression Herbert's answer does what you asked for.

Comment: I do not think redefining the fundamental and often-used macro `\mkbibparens` is such a good idea.

Comment: @moewe: I would like it to say [Karnik A,1999] in the "references" section, just before its actual references is listed

Comment: I've been able to use square brackets in the "references" section using this [adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries). Now all I need is a comma "," between the names and the year inside the square brackets. Can it be done please?

Answer (score 1):

Having read your new comments on Herbert's answer, I came up with the following

```
\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \begingroup
    \undef\cbx@lasthash
    \undef\cbx@lastyear
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \parencite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \endgroup
  \addspace
}
\makeatother
```

Similar to what Lockstep did in [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864), but shorter. (Of course you can use `\cite` or any other cite command instead of `\parencite` above.)

The delimiter between name and year is changed with

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

So we have

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \begingroup
    \undef\cbx@lasthash
    \undef\cbx@lastyear
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \parencite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \endgroup
  \addspace
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

foo~\parencite{baez/article,wilde}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

If you only want the comma locally (why would you though?), you can use

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \begingroup
    \undef\cbx@lasthash
    \undef\cbx@lastyear
    \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
    \parencite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \endgroup
  \addspace
}
\makeatother
```

---

### Old answer

Instead of redefining the very fundamental `\mkbibparens`, I would go with a redefinition of `\parencite` to use `\mkbibbrackets` instead of `\mkbibparens`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Of course you could also redefine `\cite`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

or define a new command `\brackcite`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Even though this is slightly more code than Herbert's solution to me it seems more robust.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

foo~\parencite{baez/article,wilde}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

After you comments on Herbert's answer.

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, you can change the separator between name and year in the citation with

```
\newcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

for example.

The way the names are displayed in citations is controlled by the name format `labeldate`.
To always get last name initials, no matter what, try

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

Comment: @boudiccas Please have a look at the edited answer and comment on what you are missing.

Comment: @boudiccas If it does, you might consider accepting (and up-voting, if you have not already) this answer.

Comment: since I wrote that I've found that in the document it shows [author,date] all hyperlinked, and in the references it shows [author,date] but only the date is hyperlinked, not quite what I'm wanting. Ideally I'm looking for both sets of references to be fully hyperlinked, instead of at present, only partially.

Comment: @boudiccas If I add the code you linked to above to make the entire citation hyperlinked to my MWE above, I get full hyperlinks. If you for some reason do not get what you want, please consider to ask a new question ideally with an MWE. (But be warned that hyperlinking entire citations is quite a tricky business, especially with compressing stiles such as `authoryear-icomp`.)