# How to get an option for square brackets in \textcite?

Tags: biblatex, citing, brackets, parenthesis

Currently in the preamble I have:

```
\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        style=authoryear,
        isbn=false,
        doi=false
]{biblatex}
```

My figures´ code looks like:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Ecore_kernel.pdf}
    \caption{Kern-Elemente von Ecore}
    \label{Ecore_kernel}
    \small{(Eigene Darstellung in Anlehnung an \textcite[S. 124]{Steinberg2009})}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces a fine output with no errors but the citation looks like:

```
(Eigene Darstellung in Anlehnung an Steinberg u.a. (2009, S. 124))
```

Instead of parentheses I need square brackets inside the outer parentheses, like:

```
(Eigene Darstellung in Anlehnung an Steinberg u.a. [2009, S. 124])
```

I searched for similar problems and only found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/biblatex-author-year-square-brackets) which I find a bit too much for this imho simple task. I also read the [biblatex documentation](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) which doesn´t offer info on this task regarding `\textcite{}`.

I thought of a solution like `\textcite[brackets][][S. 124]{Steinberg2009}` if that is possible.

I hope you have a nice solution :)

Comment: One very easy solution is to write `\small{\mkbibparens{Eigene Darstellung in Anlehnung an \textcite[S. 124]{Steinberg2009}}}`. That is replace the literal parentheses `(...)` by `\mkbibparens{...}`.

Comment: Wow, moewe, this is really nice! I was about to write my own `\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcitebrackets}` but this nesting feature is the better solution I think `:)`

Comment: You don't give an MWE so I haven't tested but what about `{\small \parentext{Eigene Darstellung in Anlehnung an \textcite[S. 124]{Steinberg2009}}}`? By the way, `\small` is a font switch: it does not take an argument.

Comment: @moewe You mean `{\small ...}` I'm assuming?

Comment: @cfr Of course I should have meant that, absolutely. I didn't really think about the command in front when I copied it, ... turns out I should have.

Comment: Note that there is no need to manually insert the abbreviation "S.", `biblatex` can do that for you automatically, just go with `\textcite[124]{foo}`.

Comment: Your level of knowledge is incredible. But as for the `S.` I discovered inconsistencies between `\parencite` and `\textcite` so I put `S.` in `\textcite` where I don´t have to and in `\parencite` where I have to, to get consistency in my .tex-files.

Comment: That inconsistency in the handling of the postnote between `\parencite` and `\textcite` is odd. The normal `authoryear` style adds the correct page prefix for both (all commands ultimately call `\printfield{postnote}`). Did you change something more with `biblatex` (especially something related to `postnote`)?

Comment: @moewe: To be honest, I don´t know. My preamble is longer than the holy bible ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `biblatex`'s nesting features for parentheses.
`biblatex` can keep track of the nesting level and automatically chooses the right form of brackets (either `(...)` or `[...]`) depending on the level. (There also is a maximum level of nesting for parentheses, which can be changed with `maxparens` the default is three.)

The easiest way then is to use one of `biblatex`'s commands with parentheses tracking, replace the literal parentheses `(...)` by `\parentext{...}` (\or `mkbibparens{...}`). For example

```
{\small \parentext{Eigene Darstellung in Anlehnung an \textcite[124]{Steinberg2009}}}
```

Since `\parentext` is defined via `\newrobustcmd*{\parentext}{\mkbibparens}` in `biblatex.sty`, you can also use `\mkbibparens` instead of `\parentext` , the latter simply being an alias for the former.

It might be an interesting debate which command to prefer. `\parentext` is listed in §3.7.5 *Text Commands* these *text commands* are "[...] are intended for use in the flow of text" (p. 89 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). While `\mkbibparens` is a "generic command which wraps its argument in parentheses" (p. 225) and is listed in §4.10.4 *Auxiliary Commands and Hooks*.

---

You can also define commands to track parentheses manually

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\openpar}{%
  \global\advance\blx@parenlevel\@ne
  \global\advance\c@parenlevel\@ne}
\newcommand{\closepar}{%
  \global\advance\blx@parenlevel\m@ne
  \global\advance\c@parenlevel\m@ne}
\makeatother
```

Using `\openpar` before or after a manually inserted `(` tells `biblatex` you opened a bracket, and then after a `)` you can close it for the tracker via `\closepar`. As in

```
(\openpar\textcite{geer})\closepar
```

Since this seems to require quite a lot of remembering and the use of two commands, the other method seems preferable.

Comment: Useful precision: in order to disable automatic turning of nested parentheses into brackets, use package option `parentracker=false`.