# Nested parentheses from citations to brackets (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago, parentheses

I was looking for a way to get `biblatex`'s `\autocite{}` command to change the parentheses from normal parentheses to brackets if issued within a stretch of text enclosed by parentheses, but was unable to find anything either here, or in the `biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` manuals.

Consider this MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, parentracker=true, cmsdate=both]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  author = {Antelope, Alfred},
  year = {2010},
  title = {A Title},
  url = {www.url.com},
  urldate = {2015-05-05},  
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {3--15}
}
@article{test2,
  author = {Bee, Ben},
  year = {2011},
  origyear = {1960},
  title = {Best Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {3--4}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

Text (in parenthesis \autocite{test1})

Text (in parenthesis \autocite{test2})

\end{document}
```

It gives me:

> Text (in parenthesis (Antelope 2010))
>   Text (in parenthesis (Bee [1960] 2011))

but I was hoping for

> Text (in parenthesis [Antelope 2010])
>   Text (in parenthesis [Bee (1960) 2011])

I originally thought that `parentracker=true` would take care of that automatically, but it seems to be there for a different purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` can only track brackets/parentheses that were set using its commands, literal `(` and `)` are not tracked.

Use `\parentext` (or `\mkbibparens`) instead of literal `(` and `)`.

```
Text \parentext{in parenthesis \autocite{test1}}

Text \parentext{in parenthesis \autocite{test2}}
```

gives

> Text (in parenthesis [Antelope 2010])
>
> Text (in parenthesis [Bee (1960)2011])

See also [How to get an option for square brackets in \textcite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254871/35864)

---

You *could* also make `(` and `)` active so that they automatically use `biblatex`'s `\bibopenparen` and `\bibcloseparen`. That can cause some really bad trouble though since it makes `(` and `)` active characters.

I would advise against making `(` and `)` active.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, parentracker=true, cmsdate=both]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\catcode`(=\active
\catcode`)=\active
\def({\bibopenparen}
\def){\bibclosebracket}

\begin{document}
Text (in parenthesis \autocite{sigfridsson})

Text (in parenthesis \autocite{kullback:reprint})
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!    One quick follow up: what is the difference between `\mkbibparens` and `\parentext` if there is one?

Comment: @jan In `biblates.sty` we have `\newrobustcmd*{\parentext}{\mkbibparens}`. From what I could find in the documentation, I'm lead to believe that `\parentext` is the higher-level command, so I suggest you use that.

Comment: I had another idea:  Would it be terribly wrong or dangerous to define  `\let\(=\bibopenparen`  and  `\let\)=\bibclosebracket` and then use `\(` and `\)` where needed?  Works with the MWE but I want to make sure that I won't break anything elsewhere ...

Comment: @jan Mhh, `\(` starts math mode (in LaTeX not TeX, so you can write `\(a\)` instead of `$a$`). So it might not be the best idea to overwrite that...

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe I can use `\<` and `\>` then. A search didn't bring up anything meaningful for these.