# How to change citations in the text from brackets to parentheses?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

My problem is as follows: I composed my thesis using the thesis template provided by Matthias Pospiech (http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/latex/vorlagen/) He used the `biblatex` package for bibliographies.

OK, now I had a look at the specifications of my faculty regarding styles and co. And according to these guidelines I have to use parentheses for the citations in the text, e.g., `(42)` rather then brackets, e.g., `[42]`.

Now that all my writing is done I want to make as little changes as possible. I thought about using

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibbrackets}[1]{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

Good news is: It works and all my references are now cited in parentheses. However, I'd like to know if this is some kind of quick'n'dirty hack and if there is a more elegant way to get parentheses (for the next time...).

Comment: For reference, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16792/45161) gives a good solution if nested parentheses are needed. It achieves the opposite effect, turning parentheses into brackets, but I suspect it can be modified fairly easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing these lines in your preamble should do the trick:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: Thx, indeed it does... However, I'd like to know, what's the benefit of this solution compared to \renewcommand... ?

Comment: It replaces bib brackets with parentheses only for citations. `\mkbibbrackets` is also used in other contexts, where you may not want any replacement.

Comment: @hatze While this solution might be longer code-wise it is certainly cleaner from a semantic perspective. You don't want all square brackets to be round brackets, you just want your citations to be wrapped in round brackets. Of course a modification of `\textcite` will require a bit more code (it is still quite straightforward, though).

Comment: Thx for the explanations. I agree and will use @Bernard's solution.

Comment: @hatze If you want your bibliography list to use round brackets, you might want to add `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` and maybe even `\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` as well.