# Citations in beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, citing

I find that the majority of presenters use, in their presentations, a citation like `[author1-author2 'last two digits of the year]` as in [here](http://susy2013.ictp.it/lecturenotes/01_Monday/Formal_SUSY/Jacot.pdf). So, I wonder if they just write this manually?, and what is the best seize to use?

[image]

Comment: Using external scripts it is possible to capture the information automatically. But If you are not going to mention teens of citations, do it manually! So that you can choose the style freely. For instance, write `Knuth` or `Knu` if he is *really* famous and write `Donald E. Knuth` to, say, distinguish from two Knuths when necessary.

Comment: If otherwise you need a bunch of citations, you can always do it as you always do with other `\documentclass`es. Beamer, in this case, makes no difference.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you for your comment. I added an image of an example of what meant.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16765/18228

Comment: I do it manually. Way easier and simpler than anything.

Comment: @percusse, thanks a lot, what about the best size for it ?

Comment: Size of the text is the same, I only use brackets around the citation (at max first two authors and the year). Then at the end frame, I basically copy paste the names, the journal name and the DOI or publisher as a itemized list. That gives me no hassle.

Comment: @percusse, this is exactly what I was wondering about, I will be so happy if you can write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was supposed to be a comment but was to long. So it is not really an answer:

In my opinion you wouldn't need any citations in your presentation if you wouldn't have too much text on your slide.

1. A presentation should only support your talk, so you could let
   your audience hear the quote instead of letting them read it.
2. If the quote has to be on your slide: don't interrupt your talk
   (the flow of important information) just to point at the citation?
   And avoid the audience is reading your credits rather than listening
   to you.

I think there is no need to "present" credits. If you must: put it on the last slide after the obligatory "Thank you" slide.

Or: instead of presenting your credits put it in the handout where people would take notice of it after they consumed the topic. In the handout you could handle the citations just as usual (in an article or so).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Most of theoretical Physicists put citations in their presentations as for example in [here](http://susy2013.ictp.it/lecturenotes/01_Monday/Formal_SUSY/Jacot.pdf) . I think it is useful to do so, since it make easy, for who interested, to go deeply in what you just mention in your presentation.

Comment: For that reason handout exist. A handoud should be more than a printed version of the presentation. A presentation which can be used unmodified as a handout is a slideument but not a good presentation. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: There is a good explanation on presentationzen: http://www.presentationzen.com/presentationzen/2006/04/slideuments_and.html