# Changing parenthesis of biblatex-apa (mimic 2017 acmart)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, acmart

I would like to closely mimic the [new 2017 ACM citation style](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) (`\citestyle{acmauthoryear}` and `\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}`). As far as I know, there is no style in biblatex that adapts it (any other suggestions to make this style work without `\documentclass{acmart}` appreciated).

I am quite happy with `biblatex-apa`, but I would like to change the parenthesis of `\parencite` and `\textcite` from `(` to `[`.

`\parencite` now: `(Doe & Nakamoto, 2017)`; wanted: `[Doe & Nakamoto, 2017]`

`\textcite` now: `Doe and Nakamoto (2017)`; wanted: `Doe and Nakamoto [2017]`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}


\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

@inproceedings{John,
 author = {Doe, John and Nakamoto, Satoshi},
 title = {Some title},
 year = {2017},
}

\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{document}

\parencite{John}
\textcite{John}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `biblatex-apa` is a very specific style that tries to implement all the requirements of the APA manual of style. If you want to implement a different style it is usually better to start from one of the standard styles and modify those instead of taking an already heavily modified and specialised style such as `biblatex-apa` or `biblatex-chicago`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Nonetheless, I am already quite happy with `biblatex-apa`, basically only the parenthesis are a dealbreaker.

Comment: If you plan to publish with the ACM you should probably forget about `biblatex`. Very few publishers (if any) accept `biblatex` submissions (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). The `acmguide` states: "You can disable loading of `natbib` using the option `natbib=false` in `\documentclass`. However, it is not recommended, as well as the use of BibTeX styles other than `ACM-Reference-Format.bst`, and may delay the processing of the manuscript."

Comment: I am not publishing to ACM, I just like the style. I tried using `natbib` with `ACM-Reference-Format.bst`, but unless I did something wrong it didn't really looked as intended without actually using `\citestyle{acmauthoryear}` which is only available with `\documentclass{acmart}`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you insist on `biblatex-apa` maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16765/35864 can help you. `\begin{ad}`If you wanted to switch my [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) styles (those styles are slight extensions of the standard styles that aim to be as customisable as the standard styles while offering a few more options), you could look into `\DeclareInnerCiteDelims` and `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims`.`\end{ad}`

Comment: In your MWE the accepted answer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16765/35864 works, so that is definitely one you should check out. Do let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Very good, your question is a duplicate then and I have voted to close as such.