# Citation brackets using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, brackets

I'm using `biblatex` for references and citations in my thesis.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

gives me the author name in the text, but I would like to have brackets around it. How would I do that?

Comment: `\parencite` gives you round brackets (parentheses). If you want square brackets a tad more work is needed. Do you really combine `style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear,`? If there is no other code to combine these two styles the output will be a bit odd.

Answer (score 3):

With `(cite)style=authoryear` `\parencite` gives you round brackets (parentheses) by default. It is possible to switch to square brackets as shown in [Biblatex, author-year, square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16765/35864). If you use `biblatex-ext` it is slightly more comfortable to do that with the command `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson} -- \parencite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998] – [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998]]