# How to have completely-hyperlinked authoryear citations using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to combine the answers of @moewe, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480054/citation-brackets-using-biblatex), and @lockstep, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear), to get completely-hyperlinked authoryear citations using biblatex as follows.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true, bibstyle=authoryear,style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

%to be put citations in brackets
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

%%% To make author hyperlink, just like year, in citations
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=violet, citecolor=violet]{hyperref}                   

\begin{document}

\parencite{A01}

\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

The result is completely hyperlinked, although the surrounding elements are parentheses rather then brackets.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that `bibstyle=authoryear,style=ext-authoryear` is redundant and equivalent to `style=ext-authoryear`. `style` sets both `bibstyle` and `citestyle`, so the later `style` overwrites the earlier `bibstyle`. `defernumbers=true,` is generally not needed with non-numeric styles.

Comment: `\bibliography` takes the file name of the bibliography database *without* extension, so `\bibliography{\jobname.bib}` should be `\bibliography{\jobname}`. On modern systems it is no longer an issue to wrongly include the `.bib` extension, but until very recently MikTeX's BibTeX would not find the `.bib` file in that case. With `biblatex` `\addbibresource` is preferred over `\bibliography` anyway. In `\addbibresource` you must include the file extension. So `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-ext`'s `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims` is usually implemented via the wrapper definition of the cite command. To wit `\parencite` is defined in the standard `authoryear.cbx` as

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

but `ext-authoryear.cbx` has

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkouterparencitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

So if you redefine `\parencite` you need to preserve `\mkouterparencitedelims`. Hence,

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

would have to be

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=violet, citecolor=violet]{hyperref}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkouterparencitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Something is a bit off here, though. That definition of `\parencite` only prints the year (`\usebibmacro{citeyear}`). It looks more like the definition of `\parencite*`. For the full  citation you'd need `\usebibmacro{cite}`.

Note that you could run into trouble with double link targets if you just said

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkouterparencitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

something like

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=violet, citecolor=violet]{hyperref}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkouterparencitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[citehyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

is safer in that regard (see [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864)).

[image: [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998]]