# LyX - Biblatex square brackets

Tags: biblatex, lyx, citing

I am working with LyX (I have no experience with writing documents in  LaTeX). I have prepared my citation library with JabRef, imported it into LyX.
I need all my citations in square brackets (in text), but when I try to change it there is no option to set it to square (in citation menu).
So no it looks like this:

```
Fisher et al. 2014
```

but I would need it like this:

```
[Fisher et al. 2014].
```

My current settings are:
[image]

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/biblatex-author-year-square-brackets) thread, but when I add this code to preamble:

```
\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother
```

I am getting the error:
[image]

My lyx file is available [here](https://owncloud.cesnet.cz/index.php/s/4bThauW4Jd6OTDE)

Here is small piece of code:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass scrbook
\begin_preamble
\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother

% increases link area for cross-references and autoname them
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
 \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}[1]{}
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}
}

% in case somebody want to have the label "Equation"
%\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{Equation~(\negthinspace\autoref{#1})}


% that links to image floats jumps to the beginning
% of the float and not to its caption
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}
%\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}

% the pages of the TOC is numbered roman
% and a pdf-bookmark for the TOC is added
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \frontmatter
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}
  \myTOC
  \mainmatter }

% makes caption labels bold
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\setcapindent{1em}

% enables calculations
\usepackage{calc}

% fancy page header/footer settings
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

% increases the bottom float placement fraction
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.5}

% avoids that floats are placed above its sections
\let\mySection\section\renewcommand{\section}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySection}
\end_preamble
\options intoc,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,BCOR10mm,captions=tableheading,titlepage
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
customHeadersFooters
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language czech
\language_package babel
\inputencoding utf8
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "lmodern" "default"
\font_sans "lmss" "default"
\font_typewriter "lmtt" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command bibtex
\index_command default
\float_placement h
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing single
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_title "Your title"
\pdf_author "Your name"
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered true
\pdf_bookmarksopen true
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder true
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle false
\pdf_quoted_options "pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false"
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 2
\use_package amssymb 2
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine biblatex-natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plainnat
\biblatex_bibstyle authoryear
\biblatex_citestyle authoryear
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\use_minted 0
\branch NoChildDocument
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #ff0000
\end_branch
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip medskip
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style german
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Left Header
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
chaptername
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset space ~
\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thechapter
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
rightmark
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Note Note
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Enable page headers and add the chapter to the header line.
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Right Header
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
leftmark
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Left Footer
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thepage
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Center Footer

\end_layout

\begin_layout Center Footer
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thepage
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter
test test test
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citealt
key "Fisher2014"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citealt
key "Fisher2017"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citealt
key "Hildebrand2013"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citealt
key "Khan2012"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand cite
key "Scheffer2017,Engel2001,ILAE"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
btprint "btPrintCited"
bibfiles "citation_library_disertacka"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Branch NoChildDocument
inverted 0
status open

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
btprint "btPrintCited"
bibfiles "citation_library_disertacka"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset nomencl_print
LatexCommand printnomenclature
set_width "custom"
width "2.5cm"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

I made export to LaTeX (by Lyx - file - Export - LaTeX plain

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,czech,intoc,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,BCOR10mm,captions=tableheading,titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\PassOptionsToPackage{natbib=true}{biblatex}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Your title},
 pdfauthor={Your name},
 pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother

% increases link area for cross-references and autoname them
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
 \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}[1]{}
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}
}

% in case somebody want to have the label "Equation"
%\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{Equation~(\negthinspace\autoref{#1})}


% that links to image floats jumps to the beginning
% of the float and not to its caption
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}
%\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}

% the pages of the TOC is numbered roman
% and a pdf-bookmark for the TOC is added
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \frontmatter
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}
  \myTOC
  \mainmatter }

% makes caption labels bold
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\setcapindent{1em}

% enables calculations
\usepackage{calc}

% fancy page header/footer settings
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

% increases the bottom float placement fraction
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.5}

% avoids that floats are placed above its sections
\let\mySection\section\renewcommand{\section}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySection}

\makeatother

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citation_library_disertacka.bib}
\begin{document}

\lhead[\chaptername~\thechapter]{\rightmark}

\rhead[\leftmark]{}

\lfoot[\thepage]{}

\cfoot{}

\cfoot[]{\thepage}

\chapter{test test test}

\citealt{Fisher2014}

\citealt{Fisher2017}

\citealt{Hildebrand2013}

\citealt{Khan2012}

\citealt{Scheffer2017,Engel2001,ILAE}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small *compilable* code?

Comment: Here is sample, with added section copied from previous thread

Comment: This is not a pure LaTeX code, I can't compile it.

Comment: updated with export to LaTeX plain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the best way to do this is to use the `ext-authoryear` style from the `biblatex-ext` package. `ext-authoryear` is a drop in replacement for `authoryear` style with extra features for customisation. For a similar example not using LyX, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480059/87678).

Then you just need three lines in your preamble:

```
% load biblatex in preamble because LyX loads it after the preamble section
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}

% use square brackets for parencite
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
% use square brackets for date in textcite
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
```

The only thing to watch is that you pass the same options to `biblatex` in the preamble set up as in the bibliography document options in LyX otherwise you will get an option clash.

A MWE LyX file becomes:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine biblatex
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblatex_bibstyle ext-authoryear
\biblatex_citestyle ext-authoryear
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
Filler text 
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand autocite
key "baez/article"
literal "false"

\end_inset

.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citet
key "bertram"
literal "false"

\end_inset

 says filler text.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
btprint "btPrintCited"
bibfiles "biblatex-examples"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

The corresponding LaTeX file exported from LyX is:

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite{baez/article}.

\textcite{bertram} says filler text.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: After few hours of trying to sort it out, this was the right way! Thank you very much David!