# How to link and highlight the year only, instead of the author name and year together

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib

I am using **hyperref** to color my links, and using author year citation style. I cite a lot of works and so my text looks like a mess of black text and colored text now.

How can I just highlight the year instead of the author name and year together ? Is it possible to remove the link from the author name ?

This is the current output and desired output:
[image]

In **tex** file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=red}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 

% --------------------------------------------- %

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{xu2005survey}, some text \cite{xu2005survey}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

In **bib** file

```
@article{xu2005survey,
  title={Survey of clustering algorithms},
  author={Xu, Rui and Wunsch, Donald},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on neural networks},
  volume={16},
  number={3},
  pages={645--678},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Ieee}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hyperlink only the year part when using natbib and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23227/how-to-hyperlink-only-the-year-part-when-using-natbib-and-hyperref)