# How to remove hyperref/colour for Author only in the Author-Year Citation Natbib LaTeX?

Tags: hyperref, natbib, etoolbox

I would like to remove the colour only for the Author Name in the citation created using natbib + bibliography for Springer (svjour3) journal manuscript.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,referee]{svjour3}
\smartqed  
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{kannan2013} ....... \\
\citet{kannan2013}

\begin{thebibliography}{300}
\bibitem[Kannan and Santhi(2013)]{kannan2013} Kannan, M. R., \& Santhi, M. H. (2013). Constructability Assessment of Climbing Formwork Systems using Building Information Modeling. \textit{Procedia Engineering}, 64, 1129-1138.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All you need to do is find [@Audrey's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27311/5001) and copy all the material beginning with `\makeatletter` and ending with `\makeatother` into your document's preamble, right after `\usepackage{etoolbox}`. Incidentally, you should load both `natbib` and `etoolbox` *before*, not after, `url` and `hyperref`.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load both the `cite` and the `natbib` citation management packages.